# C# equivalent of Java's Long.numberOfLeadingZeros

Tags: c#, java, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# - count leading zeroes in an Int32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10439242/c-sharp-count-leading-zeroes-in-an-int32)

I'm looking for the C# equivalent to this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#numberOfLeadingZeros(long)

From the Java docs:

> Returns the number of zero bits preceding the highest-order
>   ("leftmost") one-bit in the two's complement binary representation of
>   the specified long value.

Hopefully it is already implemented somewhere...

Comment: @coder, no that's a trailing zeros

Comment: Looks like better cross class coordination in solving homework is needed - same question in 5 minutes from 2 different people is suspicious :) - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10439242/c-sharp-count-leading-zeroes-in-an-int32.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov no not homework, but I admit that is strange... meanwhile found this implemented in Java Lucene's BitUtils - not sure why the implemented it when they had this available in the framework...