# How to efficiently apply polynomials in C++ without a loop?

Tags: c++, c++20, polynomial-approximations

I want to get accurate approximations of some complex functions (`pow`, `exp`, `log`, `log2`...) faster than ones provided by cmath in C++'s standard library.

To do this I want to exploit the way the floating point is encoded and get exponent and mantissa using bit manipulations, and then do polynomial approximations. The mantissa is between 1 and 2 so I use nth order polynomial to approximate the target function in the domain x in [1, 2], and do bit manipulations and simple math to the float expression to make the calculations work.

I used `np.polyfit` to generate the polynomials. As an example, the following is the 7th order polynomial I use to approximate log2 on 1 <= x <= 2:

```py
P = np.array(
    [
        0.01459855,
        -0.17811046,
        0.95074541,
        -2.91450247,
        5.67353733,
        -7.39616658,
        7.08511059,
        -3.23521156,
    ],
    dtype=float,
)
```

To apply the polynomial, sum the first term times x raised to 7th power and second term times x raised to 6th power, and so on...

In code:

```py
P[0] * x**7 + P[1] * x**6 + P[2] * x**5 + P[3] * x**4 + P[4] * x**3 + P[5] * x**2 + P[6] * x + P[7]
```

Of course this is very inefficient, bigger powers are computed first, so there are a lot of duplicate calculations, if we reverse the order, we can calculate the current power from the previous power, like so:

```
PR = P[::-1]
s = 0
c = 1
for i in PR:
    s += i * c
    c *= x
```

And that is exactly what I do in C++:

```cpp
constexpr double LOG2_POLY7[8] = {
    -3.23521156,
    7.08511059,
    -7.39616658,
    5.67353733,
    -2.91450247,
    0.95074541,
    -0.17811046,
    0.01459855,
};
constexpr float FU = 1.0 / (1 << 23);

inline float fast_log2_accurate(float f) {
    uint32_t bits = *reinterpret_cast<uint32_t*>(&f);
    int e = ((bits >> 23) & 0xff) - 127;
    double m1 = 1 + (bits & 0x7fffff) * FU;
    double s = 0;
    double m = 1;
    for (const double& p : LOG2_POLY7) {
        s += p * m;
        m *= m1;
    }
    return e + s;
}
```

It is much faster than log2 from cmath, while getting the same accuracy:

```
log2(3.1415927f) = 1.651496171951294 : 42.68856048583984 nanoseconds
fast_log2_accurate(3.1415927f) = 1.651496171951294 : 9.967899322509766 nanoseconds
```

I compiled with Visual Studio 2022, compiler flags:

```
/permissive- /ifcOutput "x64\Release\" /GS /GL /W3 /Gy /Zc:wchar_t /Zi /Gm- /O2 /Ob1 /sdl /Fd"x64\Release\vc143.pdb" /Zc:inline /fp:fast /D "NDEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /std:c17 /Gd /Oi /MD /std:c++20 /FC /Fa"x64\Release\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"x64\Release\" /Ot /Fp"x64\Release\exponentiation.pch" /diagnostics:column /arch:AVX2
```

However I think it can be more efficient. There is a loop overhead, and if I can optimize the loop out, it should be faster.

How can I apply the polynomial without loop?

---

If the loop is already unrolled, then is it possible to do the calculation using SIMD instructions to make it even faster?

---

I have benchmarked the solutions provided below, and some other functions I wrote before:

```
#include <vector>
#include <numbers>
using std::vector;

using std::numbers;
using numbers::ln2;
using numbers::pi;

constexpr double LOG2_POLY7[8] = {
    -3.23521156,
    7.08511059,
    -7.39616658,
    5.67353733,
    -2.91450247,
    0.95074541,
    -0.17811046,
    0.01459855,
};
constexpr float FU = 1.0 / (1 << 23);

inline float fast_log2_accurate(float f) {
    uint32_t bits = std::bit_cast<uint32_t>(f);
    int e = ((bits >> 23) & 0xff) - 127;
    double m1 = 1 + (bits & 0x7fffff) * FU;
    double s = 0;
    double m = 1;
    for (const double& p : LOG2_POLY7) {
        s += p * m;
        m *= m1;
    }
    return e + s;
}

template <int N> inline double poly(const double* a, const float x) {
    return (a[0] + x * poly<N - 1>(a + 1, x));
}

template <> inline double poly<0>(const double* a, const float x) {
    return x * a[0];
}

inline float fast_log2_accurate2(float f) {
    uint32_t bits = std::bit_cast<uint32_t>(f);
    int e = ((bits >> 23) & 0xff) - 127;
    double m1 = 1 + (bits & 0x7fffff) * FU;
    return e + poly<8>(LOG2_POLY7, m1);
}


inline float fast_log2_accurate3(float f) {
    uint32_t bits = std::bit_cast<uint32_t>(f);
    int e = ((bits >> 23) & 0xff) - 127;
    double m1 = 1 + (bits & 0x7fffff) * FU;
    double s = 0;
    double m = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        s += LOG2_POLY7[i] * m;
        m *= m1;
    }
    return e + s;
}

vector<float> log2_float() {
    int lim = 1 << 24;
    vector<float> table(lim);
    for (int i = 0; i < lim; i++) {
        table[i] = float(log(i) / ln2) - 150;
    }
    return table;
}
const vector<float> LOG2_FLOAT = log2_float();

inline float fast_log2(float f) {
    uint32_t bits = std::bit_cast<uint32_t>(f);
    int e = (bits >> 23) & 0xff;
    int m = bits & 0x7fffff;
    return (e == 0 ? LOG2_FLOAT[m << 1] : e + LOG2_FLOAT[m | 0x00800000]);
}

inline float fast_log(float f) {
    return fast_log2(f) * ln2;
}

vector<double> log2_double() {
    int lim = 1 << 24;
    vector<double> table(lim);
    for (uint64_t i = 0; i < lim; i++) {
        table[i] = log(i << 29) / ln2 - 1075;
    }
    return table;
}
const vector<double> LOG2_DOUBLE = log2_double();

inline double fast_log2_double(double d) {
    uint64_t bits = std::bit_cast<uint64_t>(d);
    uint64_t e = (bits >> 52) & 0x7ff;
    uint64_t m = bits & 0xfffffffffffff;
    return (e == 0 ? LOG2_DOUBLE[m >> 28] : e + LOG2_DOUBLE[(m | 0x10000000000000) >> 29]);
}
```

```
fast_log2(3.1415927f) = 1.651496887207031 : 0.2610206604003906 nanoseconds
log2f(3.1415927f) = 1.651496171951294 : 33.27693939208984 nanoseconds
fast_log2_double(pi) = 1.651496060131421 : 0.3225326538085938 nanoseconds
fast_log2_accurate(3.1415927f) = 1.651496171951294 : 8.907032012939453 nanoseconds
fast_log2_accurate3(3.1415927f) = 1.651496171951294 : 7.831001281738281 nanoseconds
fast_log2_accurate2(3.1415927f) = 1.651496171951294 : 13.57889175415039 nanoseconds
```

While the two functions that use a lookup table are unbeatable, they are fairly inaccurate. I used explicitly `log2f` in my benchmark. As you can see, in MSVC it is quite slow.

The recursive function slows down the code significantly, as expected. Using an old style loop makes the code run 2 nanoseconds faster. However I wasn't able to benchmark the one that uses `std::index_sequence`, it caused compiler errors and I wasn't able to resolve it.

---

There was a bug in my code to benchmark that makes the recursive version timing inaccurate, it makes the measured time longer, I fixed that.

The solution from the newest answer:

```cpp
inline float fast_log2_accurate4(float f) {
    uint32_t bits = std::bit_cast<uint32_t>(f);
    int e = ((bits >> 23) & 0xff) - 127;
    float m = 1 + (bits & 0x7fffff) * FU;
    float s_even = LOG2_POLY7[0];
    float s_odd = LOG2_POLY7[1] * m;
    float m2 = m * m;
    float m_even = m2;
    float m_odd = m * m2;

    for (int i = 2; i < 8; i += 2) {
        s_even += LOG2_POLY7[i] * m_even;
        s_odd += LOG2_POLY7[i + 1] * m_odd;
        m_even *= m2;
        m_odd *= m2;
    }
    return e + s_even + s_odd;
}
```

```
fast_log2_accurate4(3.1415927f) = 1.651496887207031 : 17.01173782348633 nanoseconds
```

It isn't as accurate as my code and takes longer, because each iteration is more expensive.

---

The index sequence version failed to compile previously, because I used `double[8]` instead of `std::array<double, 8>`, I thought they were the same thing! After it was pointed out, I fixed that, and it compiled successfully.

Benchmark:

```
ln(256) = 5.545613288879395 : 3.985881805419922 nanoseconds
log(256) = 5.545177459716797 : 7.047939300537109 nanoseconds
fast_log2(3.1415927f) = 1.651496887207031 : 0.25787353515625 nanoseconds
log2f(3.1415927f) = 1.651496171951294 : 35.03541946411133 nanoseconds
fast_log2_double(pi) = 1.651496060131421 : 0.3331184387207031 nanoseconds
fast_log2_accurate(3.1415927f) = 1.651496171951294 : 9.366512298583984 nanoseconds
fast_log2_accurate3(3.1415927f) = 1.651496171951294 : 7.454872131347656 nanoseconds
fast_log2_accurate2(3.1415927f) = 1.651496171951294 : 14.07079696655273 nanoseconds
fast_log2_accurate4(3.1415927f) = 1.651496887207031 : 16.6351318359375 nanoseconds
fast_log2_accurate5(3.1415927f) = 1.651496171951294 : 7.868862152099609 nanoseconds
```

It turns out `ln` is extremely fast, and the only way to beat it is to use a lookup table, but it only gives 3 correct decimal digits, np.log(256) gives 5.545177444479562. In contrast, my fastest functions give 6 correct decimal digits, and is ten times faster. I only need to multiply it with `ln2` to get `ln(x)`, and it would be more accurate still.

I have benchmarked the solutions multiple times, and `fast_log2_accurate5` is the index sequence version. It and the old style loop version are consistently faster than my range based for loop version. Sometimes the for loop version is faster, sometimes the index sequence version. At this level the measured values fluctuate greatly, and I am running many other programs at the same time.

But it seems the performance of the index sequence version is much more stable than the for loop version and so I will accept it.

---

Update:

I have revisited the code, and I did just a little change to the index sequence version, I simply added `inline` in front of `do_loop` function, and this little change, makes the code run in less than a nanosecond, and I can just throw in more terms without slowing down the code too much, it would still be significantly faster than `log2` while getting very accurate results.

In contrast the `std::apply` version is slow, even with inline:

```
constexpr std::array<double, 8> LOG2_POLY7A = {
    -3.23521156,
    7.08511059,
    -7.39616658,
    5.67353733,
    -2.91450247,
    0.95074541,
    -0.17811046,
    0.01459855,
};

template <std::size_t... I>
inline double do_loop(double m1, std::index_sequence<I...>) {
    double s = 0;
    double m = 1;
    ((s += std::get<I>(LOG2_POLY7A) * m, m *= m1), ...);
    return s;
}

inline float fast_log2_accurate5(float f) {
    uint32_t bits = std::bit_cast<uint32_t>(f);
    int e = ((bits >> 23) & 0xff) - 127;
    double m1 = 1 + (bits & 0x7fffff) * FU;
    double s = do_loop(m1, std::make_index_sequence<8>{});
    return e + s;
}

inline double do_loop1(double m1) {
    double s = 0;
    double m = 1;
    auto worker = [&](auto&...term) {
        ((s += term * m, m *= m1), ...);
        };
    std::apply(worker, LOG2_POLY7A);
    return s;
}

inline float fast_log2_accurate6(float f) {
    uint32_t bits = *reinterpret_cast<uint32_t*>(&f);
    int e = ((bits >> 23) & 0xff) - 127;
    double m1 = 1 + (bits & 0x7fffff) * FU;
    double s = do_loop1(m1);
    return e + s;
}
```

```
fast_log2_accurate5(3.1415927f) = 1.651496171951294 : 0.9766578674316406 nanoseconds
fast_log2_accurate6(3.1415927f) = 1.651496171951294 : 7.168102264404297 nanoseconds
```

Comment: I'd presume a near 100% certainty that basic floating point functions, like `pow()`, et. al. get compiled to a single CPU instruction that executes it using hardware registers, and the likelyhood of coming up with a homegrown alternative that turns out to be faster, are not very promising.

Comment: `uint32_t bits = *reinterpret_cast<uint32_t*>(&f);` is undefined behavior.  You probably wanted to do `uint32_t bits; memcpy(&bits, &f, sizeof bits);`

Comment: @SamVarshavchik `pow()` is very certainly not a single instruction. Here is [glibc's version](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/sysdeps/ieee754/flt-32/e_powf.c). That being said, getting faster will certainly be an achievement.

Comment: @Eljay Or in C++20 `uint32_t bits = std::bit_cast<uint32_t>(f);`

Comment: I doubt that your approach has the same accuracy as the libc implementations. Standard library implementations like glibc typically guarantee something like at most 1 or few ULP error, but your use of addition seems prone to introduce many more. It doesn't look numerically stable.

Comment: Have a look at other approximating functions (e.g. Pade approximants). I can’t see a polynomial being a particularly good fit to a log function.

Comment: @lastchance Right, it can only possibly be a decent approximation in a narrow band.

Comment: Hard to tell with the code provided, but is the `log2` timing using the `log2(double)`? If so, probably should either use `std::log2(float)` or `std::log2f(float)` as a better comparison.

Comment: In my tests your code is about 1.5-2 times slower than the standard library log (tested with gcc and clang)

Comment: Pow, log2, log, cos, sin used to be single instructions on x87 (taking hundreds of clock cycles for the elementary functions) - on AVX2 / NEON era the best we can get is (fused) multiply accumulate, sqrt and division.

Comment: Noted that for `index_sequence` version, `LOG2_POLY7` should be `std::array` not raw array.

Comment: To unroll loops there is always Duffs device (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device) although compiler sometimes will perform loop unrolling automatically.

Comment: In [Quickbench](https://quick-bench.com/q/iSBpzh4VQHDEGZGymOJ4uRdc5rs) I see that every one of these *is* using SSE instructions (except for fast_log2_accurate2, which cheated)

Comment: I think `fast_log2_accurate2` has some undefined behavior, because [clang is optimizing it out even when given random inputs.](https://quick-bench.com/q/FqWajTuXQHYJvvw4dpkNmv_3oMw)

Comment: It appears that the use of `float` vs `double` for internal calculations does not affect performance much https://quick-bench.com/q/oVE8AEiVvGPFnqAit_IdIG3YU-c  I am surprised, clang doesn't seem to have used an SSE packed multiply (`MULPS`) for *any* of these.

Comment: Sprinkling in `#pragma clang fp exceptions(ignore) contract(fast) reassociate(on)` and `__attribute__((optimize("-ffast-math")))` does not appear to have meaningfully affected the results https://quick-bench.com/q/sfUB6weXAwq32WLlF0hAaGXMLS0

Comment: On a whim I made a function that uses a map of 16 linear approximations. https://quick-bench.com/q/B-WN-1UnOZxn5iLqHyclvkFhvXU It's about 2.3x faster than the next fastest here, but is only accurate to... about 3 digits. 

Comment: @MooingDuck See my comment in the other question to increase accuracy https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77133222/c-log2-implementation-for-double-using-bit-hacking#comment135983682_77133222 The value specifically for 3 and the calculation at pi are just examples for the formula. It needs one accurate value and can then calculate more values more accurate than linear interpolation for the cost of a division.

Comment: This `fast_log2_accurate4` is meant to be called with `float Lut[8]`, not `double Lut[8]`, which will cause unnecessary runtime conversions. The intended speedup comes at the cost of accuracy obviously and being able to compute the even/odd sequences with instruction-level-parallelism.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can unroll the loop with `std::index_sequence`, as follows:

```
#include <array>
#include <cstdint>
#include <utility>

constexpr std::size_t size_log2 = 8;

constexpr std::array<double, size_log2> LOG2_POLY7 = {
    -3.23521156,
    7.08511059,
    -7.39616658,
    5.67353733,
    -2.91450247,
    0.95074541,
    -0.17811046,
    0.01459855,
};
constexpr float FU = 1.0 / (1 << 23);

template <std::size_t... I>
double do_loop(double m1, std::index_sequence<I...>) {
    double s = 0;
    double m = 1;
    ((s += std::get<I>(LOG2_POLY7) * m, m *= m1),...);
    return s;
}

inline float fast_log2_accurate(float f) {
    uint32_t bits = *reinterpret_cast<uint32_t*>(&f);
    int e = ((bits >> 23) & 0xff) - 127;
    double m1 = 1 + (bits & 0x7fffff) * FU;
    double s = do_loop(m1, std::make_index_sequence<size_log2>{});
    return e + s;
}
```

Test the code on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/a1j1Exc8E).

Notice that I have also moved the variable `m` insides the `do_loop` function, as it is only required there. And, per suggestion in the comments, `do_loop` returns the result which was stored in the variable `s` in the question.
Compared to your initial version, this unrolling of the loop is done at compile time, and avoids, for instance, to compare `p` with `LOG2_POLY7.end()` at every iteration. As always, the actual gain should be benchmarked.

Also, as noted in the comments, the loop can be simplified by using `std::apply` to convert the array `LOG2_POLY7` into variadic arguments; see below or the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77151814/8769985).

As asked in the comment, one can generalize the `do_loop` function to work for a generic `std::array`. This implies however an additional routine. This is because, in the `do_loop` above, the *type* of the `index_sequence` is determined by the nontype template parameters `std::size_t... I`; these parameters, and hence the type of the second parameter of `do_loop` are deduced.
Now, given a generic `std::array`, you can deduce the size `N`, but to make the `do_loop` work you need to convert this `N` to a sequence of indices `0...N-1`: That's precisely what `index_sequence` is for.

So, for a more generic routine one can substitute the code above with:

```
template <std::size_t N, std::size_t... I>
double do_loop_impl(double m1, const std::array<double, N>& data, std::index_sequence<I...>) {
    double s = 0;
    double m = 1;
    ((s += std::get<I>(data) * m, m *= m1),...);
    return s;
}

template <std::size_t N>
double do_loop(double m1, const std::array<double, N>& data) {
    return do_loop_impl(m1, data, std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
}

inline float fast_log2_accurate(float f) {
    uint32_t bits = *reinterpret_cast<uint32_t*>(&f);
    int e = ((bits >> 23) & 0xff) - 127;
    double m1 = 1 + (bits & 0x7fffff) * FU;
    double s = do_loop(m1, LOG2_POLY7);
    return e + s;
}
```

Alternatively, one can use `std::apply`, slightly generalizing the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77151814/8769985):

```
template <std::size_t N>
double do_loop(double m1, const std::array<double, N>& data) {
    return std::apply([m1](auto... p) {
                      double s = 0;
                      double m = 1;
                      ((s += p * m, m *= m1), ...);
                      return s; }, data);
}

inline float fast_log2_accurate(float f) {
    uint32_t bits = *reinterpret_cast<uint32_t*>(&f);
    int e = ((bits >> 23) & 0xff) - 127;
    double m1 = 1 + (bits & 0x7fffff) * FU;
    double s = do_loop(m1, LOG2_POLY7);
    return e + s;
}
```

(Remember to `include <tuple>` if you use `std::apply`).

Finally, if you are interested in speed, you could consider SIMD vectorization, see e.g. [openMP SIMD directives](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpsu42.html), the [vector class library](https://github.com/vectorclass), the [xsimd library](https://xsimd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). This probably requires a rethinking of the loops.

Answer (score 2):

for gcc you can force unroll it using `#pragma GCC unroll n`

```
inline float fast_log2_accurate(float f) {
    uint32_t bits = *reinterpret_cast<uint32_t*>(&f);
    int e = ((bits >> 23) & 0xff) - 127;
    double m1 = 1 + (bits & 0x7fffff) * FU;
    double s = 0;
    double m = 1;
    #pragma GCC unroll 8
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        s += LOG2_POLY7[i] * m;
        m *= m1;
    }
    return e + s;
}
```

there is nothing similar for msvc, but msvc [already unrolls it at O2](https://godbolt.org/z/5P7YPePEd), while clang and gcc unroll it at O3, just don't use a range-based for loop, and use an old-style one to make it easier for msvc to unroll it, as it's the only compiler that can't unroll a range-based for loop.

---

an AVX implementation is only 10% faster than a raw loop, mostly because you can't calculate the powers of `m1` in a vectorized way.

```cpp
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <immintrin.h>

constexpr double LOG2_POLY7[8] = {
    -3.23521156,
    7.08511059,
    -7.39616658,
    5.67353733,
    -2.91450247,
    0.95074541,
    -0.17811046,
    0.01459855,
};
struct simdvec4 {
union 
{
    __m256d v;
    double a[4];
};
};

inline double AVXCalcPowers(double m1)
{
    double m = 1;
    simdvec4 vec1;
    simdvec4 vec2;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
    vec1.a[i] = m;
    m *= m1;
    }
    vec2.v = _mm256_mul_pd(vec1.v, _mm256_set_pd(m,m,m,m));
    vec1.v = _mm256_mul_pd(vec1.v, _mm256_load_pd(LOG2_POLY7));
    vec1.v = _mm256_fmadd_pd(vec2.v, _mm256_load_pd(LOG2_POLY7 + 4), vec1.v);
    vec1.v = _mm256_hadd_pd(vec1.v, vec1.v);
    return vec1.a[0] + vec1.a[2];
}

constexpr float FU = 1.0 / (1 << 23);

inline float fast_log2_accurate(float f) {
    uint32_t bits = *reinterpret_cast<uint32_t*>(&f);
    int e = ((bits >> 23) & 0xff) - 127;
    double m1 = 1 + (bits & 0x7fffff) * FU;
    double s = AVXCalcPowers(m1);
    return e + s;
}
```

you are much better off vectorizing the entire function that a part of it, ie: vectorize the calculation of powers of different `m1` s.

Comment: The powers can be kind of vectorized. E.g. m^4*(m^4, m^3, m^2, m) gives 4 more powers.

Answer (score 2):

This is the `std::apply` solution, based off of the [other great answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77145389/1774667) mentioned in comments:

```
#include <array>
#include <cstdint>
#include <utility>

constexpr std::size_t size_log2 = 8;

constexpr std::array<double, size_log2> LOG2_POLY7 = {
    -3.23521156,
    7.08511059,
    -7.39616658,
    5.67353733,
    -2.91450247,
    0.95074541,
    -0.17811046,
    0.01459855,
};
constexpr float FU = 1.0 / (1 << 23);

double do_loop(double m1) {
    double s = 0;
    double m = 1;
    auto worker = [&](auto&...term) {
      ((s += term * m, m *= m1),...);
    };
    std::apply(worker, LOG2_POLY7);
    return s;
}

inline float fast_log2_accurate(float f) {
    uint32_t bits = *reinterpret_cast<uint32_t*>(&f);
    int e = ((bits >> 23) & 0xff) - 127;
    double m1 = 1 + (bits & 0x7fffff) * FU;
    double s = do_loop(m1);
    return e + s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is simple recursive template version of the Horner algorithm for polynomials. I left out exp manipulation because it is not relevant

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

#define func auto

template <int N> inline func poly(const float* a, const float x) -> float {
    return (a[0] + x*poly<N-1>(a + 1, x));
}

template <> inline func poly<0>(const float* a, const float x) -> float {
    return x*a[0];
}

constexpr float LOG2_POLY7[8] = {
    -3.23521156f,
    7.08511059f,
    -7.39616658f,
    5.67353733f,
    -2.91450247f,
    0.95074541f,
    -0.17811046f,
    0.01459855f
};

func log22(const float x) -> float {
    return poly<sizeof(LOG2_POLY7)/sizeof(LOG2_POLY7[0])>(LOG2_POLY7, x);
}

func main() -> int {
    float x = 1.25f;
    
    std::cout << std::log2(x) << "   " << log22(x) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

tested with clang 16.0.6 on windows 11 x64. Probably fastest version due to loop unrolling done at compilation time automatically.

UPDATE

Ok, added exponent handling so it works for all floats

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

#define func auto

template <int N> inline func poly(const float* a, const float m, const float m1) -> float {
    return (m*a[0] + poly<N-1>(a + 1, m*m1, m1));
}

template <> inline func poly<0>(const float* a, const float m, const float m1) -> float {
    return m*a[0];
}

constexpr float LOG2_POLY7[8] = {
    -3.23521156f,
    7.08511059f,
    -7.39616658f,
    5.67353733f,
    -2.91450247f,
    0.95074541f,
    -0.17811046f,
    0.01459855f
};

constexpr float FU = 1.0 / (1 << 23);

func log22(float f) -> float {
    uint32_t bits = *reinterpret_cast<uint32_t*>(&f);
    int e = ((bits >> 23) & 0xff) - 127;
    
    float m1 = 1.0f + (bits & 0x7fffff) * FU;
    float m  = 1.0f;
    
    float s = poly<sizeof(LOG2_POLY7)/sizeof(LOG2_POLY7[0])>(LOG2_POLY7, m, m1);
    return s + e;
}

func main() -> int {
    float x = 97.1415927f;
    
    std::cout << std::log2(x) << "   " << log22(x) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

One can possibly make the loop a bit faster by computing even and odd phases in parallel breaking off some of the loop carried dependencies.

```
   float s_even = Lut[0]; // the constant coefficient
   float s_odd = Lut[1] * m;
   float m2 = m * m;
   float m_even = m2;
   float m_odd = m * m2;
   
   for (int i = 2; i < 8; i+=2) {
       s_even += Lut[i] * m_even;
       s_odd += Lut[i + 1] * m_odd;
       m_even *= m2;
       m_odd *= m2;
   }
   return s_even + s_odd;
```

There's no way to get rid of the loop; it can be converted to tail recursion with templates, but it's still essentially a loop.

**EDIT**
Note, that this version also requires `float Lut[8]` instead of `double Lut[8]`. Otherwise some compilers might generate a costly `double->float` conversion in the innerloop.

With `-ffast-math` and on ARM64, clang converts the dot-product portion to merely

```
        fmul    s1, s0, s0
        ldp     s3, s2, [x0]
        fmul    s2, s2, s0
        fmul    s0, s1, s0
        mov     v4.16b, v1.16b
        mov     v3.s[1], v2.s[0]
        mov     v4.s[1], v0.s[0]
        ldp     d0, d2, [x0, #8]
        fmla    v3.2s, v0.2s, v4.2s
        fmul    v0.2s, v4.2s, v1.s[0]
        fmla    v3.2s, v2.2s, v0.2s
        fmul    v0.2s, v0.2s, v1.s[0]
        ldr     d1, [x0, #24]
        fmla    v3.2s, v1.2s, v0.2s
        faddp   s0, v3.2s
        ret
```

In my benchmarks, this is about 7x faster (on Macbook M1), than the naive version which uses doubles. Of course one can gain some additional accuracy by computing the intermediate results in doubles instead of floats.