# How to pass functions of different arguments and return types as a parameter in C++

Tags: c++, c++20

I find the basic math functions like `pow`, `exp`, `log` and such from `cmath` extremely inefficient, so I decided to implement my own versions of them that are both accurate and efficient. And I did.

I use 9th order polynomial approximations over the interval [1, 2) or [0, 1) to approximate the functions, I used `numpy.polyfit` to get the polynomials, and I applied the polynomials using `std::index_sequence` which is [insanely fast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77144800/how-to-efficiently-apply-polynomials-in-c-without-a-loop), and while my methods aren't as precise as the library ones, I can get at least 13 correct decimal places with `fp:precise`, and my methods give the same precision as library code with `fp:fast`.

And now I want a function to measure the execution time of the functions and determine the accuracy of them.

Previously I just copy-paste the same lines of code for every new function I want to benchmark, and that isn't very tidy and is prone to error.

My functions are simple, all of them return a floating point number, a single value, that is either `float` or `double`. And they take one or two arguments, the second argument is a number, it can be `int`, `float` or `double` and its type makes no difference. The type of the first argument is important though, it can either be `float` or `double`, its type is the same as the return type of the function, and its type must match exactly what is declared in the function, because I use `std::bit_cast`.

As an example, the following is what I have come up with to measure the execution time of a function that takes a single `float` parameter and returns a `float`:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>

using std::chrono::steady_clock;
using std::chrono::duration;
using std::vector;
using std::function;

double timeit(const function<float(float)>& func, const vector<float>& values, int runs = 1048576){
    auto start = steady_clock::now();
    size_t len = values.size();
    for (int64_t i = 0; i < runs; i++) {
        func(values[i % len]);
    }
    auto end = steady_clock::now();
    duration<double, std::nano> time = end - start;
    return time.count() / runs;
}
```

I haven't added the verification yet, but I will add it later.

I want to know, how can I reuse the same function to benchmark a function that returns a `double`? I know of function overloading, but that would mean a function with the same function body just with a different parameter list. I guess I will have to use another function for the two argument ones but I don't want to use overloading for functions with one argument.

I know of `std::variant` but I want to compare the values and as far as I know it doesn't support comparing with constituent types.

How to solve this?

Comment: Why not a function template?

Comment: What's  wrong with cmath? A majority of them utilize HW FP instructions for rapid and accurate calculations (CORDIC is part of any modern CPU). I seriously doubt any high-level code can beat them in that regard. If this is just preface to your question, I suggest you remove it. Otherwise, ***"extremely inefficient"*** is extremely intense and unclear.

Comment: the cost of `std::function` virtual call here would eat away any performance of elementary math functions

Comment: Extraordinary claims require extraordinary proofs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a template function, eg,

```
template<typename T>
double timeit(const function<T(T)>& func, const vector<T>& values, size_t runs = 1048576){
    ...
}
```

Or even:

```
template<typename FuncType, typename ElemType>
double timeit(FuncType func, const vector<ElemType>& values, size_t runs = 1048576){
    ...
}
```

If needed, you can then use SFINAE or concepts to restrict the element data type to just the types you want.

Answer (score 1):

I think function template might work,also you can use concept(I did't remember the name clearly) to check the parameter.In my opinion,if you need to add more type of argument,function template+concept will be your best choice.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).