# Integer logarithm of fractional bases

Tags: algorithm

I'm working on a program where the problem has a natural logarithmic scale.

So far I'm using base 2, with a nice implementation of `unsigned int log2(uint64_t)` (in C/C++), [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11398748/931303).

However, I found that base 2 is too much for my problem: I need to use fractional bases, e.g. 3/2.

Is anyone aware of an implementation for this kind of operation?

My current solution is `round(log(x)/log(base))` where round returns integer, but I was hopping, at least, to avoid two evaluations of the log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`log(base)` is a constant, so just evaluate it once and take its reciprocal (to turn it onto a multiply rather than an expensive divide).

```
const float k = 1.0f / log(base); // init constant once

y = round(log(x) * k); // each evaluation only requires one log,
                       // one multiply and one round
```