# Bit masking with decimal offset: Faster algorithm?

Tags: javascript, sum, decimal, bitmask, bit-masks

I've a sum build of 0 up to 3 specific decimal numbers that can build 8 different sums:

```
  100      ---      100      ---      100      ---      100      ---
  200      200      ---      ---      200      200      ---      ---
+ 400    + 400    + 400    + 400    + ---    + ---    + ---    + ---
-----    -----    -----    -----    -----    -----    -----    -----
  700      600      500      600      300      200      100        0
```

The decimal numbers are scaled by doubling the next smaller number starting at a specific offset. They might be for example in the following sets instead:

- `{ 300, 600, 1200, ..}`
- `{ 7, 14, 28, ..}`

It is possible to figure out if a specific number is added by simply dividing by the offset and then running a bitmask check:

```
(sum / offset) & 1 == true if the first decimal number is added.
(sum / offset) & 2 == true if the second decimal number is added.
(sum / offset) & 4 == true if the third decimal number is added.
```

Is there any faster algorithm than that?

BTW: Since this is not exactly bitmasking how is it called instead? Decimal masking? Decimal sum multiplexing? Bitmasking with offset? Sum masking? WTF bit masking?

Comment: Why is it "not exactly bitmasking"? Once you divide by 100, you've got a 3-bit value, and you're using the bitwise-AND operator after all.

Comment: It's called "counting 0 bits". Have a look at [Fast computing of log2 for 64-bit integers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11376288/fast-computing-of-log2-for-64-bit-integers)