# Optimized method to find log2 using C

Tags: c, algorithm, arm

I'm looking for an efficient method (**preferably using few bitwise operations**) that returns the count of left shifts or solve the equation as:

> find x for a given y where y=2^x

For example (1 << 4) = 16 = 10000b. So if 16 is given how can I solve it for the amount of left shift which is **4** in given case. Also, I'm **not** looking for a method that involves **loop** or **log** method like:

```
unsigned int count_shift(unsigned int shifted)
{
    unsigned int count = 0;

    for (count = 0; shifted != 0x1; count++)
    {
        shifted /= 2;   
    }
    return count;
}
```

Cheers!

Comment: [Fast computing of log2 for 64-bit integers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11376288/995714)

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Bit-Twiddling Hacks FTW.

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc my question is about **efficient method in C**

Comment: Efficient on memory space, or register usage?

Comment: You may have been put off by the C# reference. But the second link from @LưuVĩnhPhúc leads to a nice and very compact answer in C: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24748784/4213662

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Even though OP's code does the same thing as the linked question, I think the question you linked is more general than OP's, because he says that the parameter is going to be 2^x.

Comment: @MartinJames for fewer CPU cycles as the code implements ISR (interrupt service routine) on an embedded platform

Comment: @SajjadAhmed OK  It's somewhat annoying that there is no simple way to do this:(

Comment: @MartinJames: I don't think it comes up that often, to be honest. You can hump it out in a handful of lines of assembler.

Comment: @Bathsheba that's what I would do in an interrupt-handler, yes.  I guess you could quickly find out which byte has the one in it and then lookup, or just rotate through carry.

Comment: @MartinJames There are some CPUs having special instructions, like ARMs CLZ (count leading zeros). One can even attempt to use `__builtin_clz`

Comment: @EugeneSh. Your answer is most relevant to the question. I'll post the implementation with its efficiency superiority.

Comment: Not a serious answer, but it would work: You could cast the `unsigned int` to a `float`, then coerce it back to `uint32_t` using a union or pointer trickery. Bits [30:23] are an offset logarithm. With some FP hardware it might be fast.

Comment: To all folks who don't know the answer and just relied on downvoting. Here is the efficient way

Comment: `unsigned int shift_count(unsigned int shifted)
   {
          return (31 - __builtin_clz(shifted));
   }`
it uses architecture's (tested on ARM-Cortex-A7 and Intel x64) **clz** instruction to calculate the leading zeros. It takes 4 cycles on the ARM and 3 cycles on x64 to calculate the log. So if you subtract it from the total bits of the input register (31 - 0) it will return you the location of the high bit.

Comment: @SajjadAhmed Nice answer. If you are able to be platform tied best to put that in the question. Might not get closed as a duplicate then. Though people are a bit keen IMHO to match with similar but not same questions.

Comment: "I'm looking for an efficient method" (speed) is a reasonable goal.  Adding  "not looking for a method that involves loop or log" is an unnecessary limitation.  For a good way to find a fast solution, next time, post test code to assess how you rate performance.

Answer (score 1):

If the number is guaranteed to be a power of two, i.e. `y == 1 << x`, you can do it with a 256-byte look-up table and four look-ups:

```
static unsigned char lookup[256] = {
    [0x01]=1, [0x02]=2, [0x04]=3, [0x08]=4, [0x10]=5, [0x20]=6, [0x40]=7, [0x80]=8
};

unsigned log2uint(unsigned y) {
    unsigned res = lookup[(y >>  0) & 0xFF];
    if (res) return res +  0 - 1;
    res = lookup[(y >>  8) & 0xFF];
    if (res) return res +  8 - 1;
    res = lookup[(y >> 16) & 0xFF];
    if (res) return res + 16 - 1;
    res = lookup[(y >> 24) & 0xFF];
    if (res) return res + 24 - 1;
    return 0;
}
```

[Demo 1](https://ideone.com/zBXAXO)

If you do not mind vendor-specific functionality, gcc provides `__builtin_ctz` function that returns the number of trailing zeros, which matches the return value that you get when `y == 1 << x` ([Demo 2](https://ideone.com/8v3iHS))

Answer (score 0):

Unless you use a lookup table<sup>1</sup>, the fastest known way is O(N):

```
unsigned int count = 0;
while (shifted >>= 1){
  ++count;
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup>Which is how `exp` and `log` are evaluated on some chips - Newton Raphson-type algorithms with lookup tables defining certain function points.

Comment: Well.. if N is number of bits, one can do it in O(log N) using binary search.. Not that it worth it for small Ns

Comment: @EugeneSh.: I'd upvote an answer written in that way; I've never seen a successful solution done like that. Not sure it would work out faster, even with 128 bit.

Comment: It won't. I just object the assertion that *the fastest known way is O(N)*.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Which I'm reluctant to withdraw until I see a well-written counter-example.

Comment: Please see here. Sorry if some corner cases were missed. https://ideone.com/S2gkUj

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Cute, but (as you know) it does have function call overheads. But it probably does par my way for a certain "sizeof".

Comment: The overheads don't turn logarithmic complexity into linear

Comment: I still put a wager on "my way" (well Stanford's way) being faster, at least up to 64 bit.

Comment: I agree and stated it in the very first comment. I consider N to be small for any standard type :)

Comment: I wonder when the cutover will occur? Long past my retirement I hope.