# How to take a base 2 logarithm from a boost int256_t?

Tags: c++, boost, logarithm, multiprecision, boost-multiprecision

So I want to take a logarithm from an int256_t.

I found this but modifying it to take sizeof int256_t did not work. It will give incorrect results:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11376759

Is there a log function in boost which supports multiprecision?

Comment: An `int256_t` is just four `int64_t`, and I would expect this built-in to support 64 bits on a 64bit platform. Substitute eight `int32_t`, for a 32bit platform. So this becomes simply a matter of finding the first non-zero `unsigned int`, that comprises the `int256_t`, using `__builtin_clz` on that, and adding the appropriate multiple of 64 or 32 to the result. A little bit more work, but still a piece of cake.

Comment: @sam plus details; if you have only 1 bit of data in your machine precision value, that may round too much.

Comment: @sam How to do it in C++ code? Maybe I am not getting your point clearly here. Can you formulate in more detail that what should be done to achieve the base 2 logarithm of an int256_t? Thanks for the comment, though.

Comment: What exactly don't you "get"? The underlying math, or the C++ code to implement it? If it's the math, I'll be happy to explain. But if you understand the math, the C++ is trivial, and is simply the direct translation of that math, so if you understand the math, but having trouble formulating that into C++ code, then you should simply ask a different question, explaining the math you're trying to calculate, all the code you've managed to write so far, and articulate what's the missing part, or is not working correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without further constraints I'd write:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4b488256ab4ded1a)</kbd>**

```
int256_t x("12345678901234567890");

std::cout << "log2(" << x << ") = " << log2(cpp_bin_float_100(x)) << "\n";
```

Prints

```
log2(12345678901234567890) = 63.4206
```

### Simpler

You don't need all that precision if you're going to round the result anyways:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/800294c4d2271140)</kbd>**

```
std::cout << "log2(" << x << ") = " << log2(x.convert_to<double>()) << "\n";
```

### Ad-hoc

A very crude form could look like:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/03ff08525ee19605)</kbd>**

```
template <typename T>
static inline int adhoc_log2(T i) {
    int n = 0;
    while(i /= 2) ++n;
    return n;
}
```

Prints

```
adhoc(12345678901234567890) = 63
```

Lastly, indeed you could drop back down to bit-level and apply the bit-fiddling hacks in the way @SamVarshavchik suggests

Answer (score 0):

```
template<class T, std::size_t...Is>
std::array<uint8_t, bytes> decomponse( std::index_sequence<Is...>, T in ) {
  return {{ (uint8_t)( in >> (8*( (sizeof...(Is)) - Is ) )) }};
}

template<std::size_t bytes, class T>
std::array<int8_t, bytes> decomponse( T in ) {
  return decompose( in, std::make_index_sequence<bytes>{} );
}

template<std::size_t bytes, class T>
double big_log2( T in ) {
  auto bytes_array = decompose<bytes>(in);
  std::size_t zeros = 0;
  for (auto byte:bytes_array) {
    if (byte) break;
    ++zeros;
  }
  int32_t tmp = 0;
  for (auto i = zeros; (i < bytes) && i < (zeros+4); ++i) {
    tmp |= bytes_array[i] << (8*(3 - (i-zeros)));
  }
  return log2(tmp) + (bytes-zeros-4)*8;
}
```

where `log2(int32_t)` generates a log2 of a 32 bit value and returns a `double`.

Depending on endianness, reversing `bytes_array` and modfying algorithm may make it faster (ideally it should compile down to a memcpy or just be optimized out entirely).

This attempts to shove the 4 highest significance bytes into a int32_t, take its logarithm, then add the right amount to shift it to the magnitude of the N-byte integer in question.