# Operations on bits, getting the bigger value

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

I'm not familiar with bitwise operations. I have this sequence:

```
1 0 0 0 0 : 16
---------------
0 1 1 1 1 : 15
---------------
0 1 1 1 0 : 14
---------------
.
.
.
---------------
0 0 0 1 1 :  3
---------------
0 0 0 1 0 :  2
---------------
0 0 0 0 1 :  1
---------------
```

I want to check first if there is more than one "1". If that's the case, I want to remove the one that has the bigger decimal value, and to finish, getting the bigger remaining. For example 15, there is four "1", I remove the bigger one, the "1" at "8", I got "0 0 1 1 1 : 7", where the bigger "1" is at "4". How can I do this?

Comment: This existing post has most of what you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/53161/find-the-highest-order-bit-in-c

Comment: Please clarify what you want exactly. Do you want to just get the lowest set bit in a number? You can get it with `x & -x`. Or do the highest bits really have to be successively removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the code that does what you want:

```
unsigned chk_bits(unsigned int x) {
    unsigned i;
    if (x != 0 && (x & (x-1)) != 0) {
        /* More than one '1' bit */
        for (i = ~(~0U >> 1); (x & i) == 0; i >>= 1)
            ; /* Intentionally left blank */
        return x & ~i;
    }
    return x;
}
```

Note that I assume you're dealing with unsigned numbers. This is usually safer, because right shifting is implementation defined on signed integers, because of sign extension.

The `if` statement checks if there's more than one bit set in `x`. `x & (x-1)` is a known way to get a number that is the same as `x` with the first '1' least significant bit turned off (for example, if `x` is `101100100`, then `x & (x-1)` is `101100000`. Thus, the `if` says:

> If x is not zero, and if turning off the first bit set to 1 (from LSB to MSB) results in something that is not 0,
>   then...

Which is equivalent to saying that there's m ore than 1 bit set in `x`.

Then, we loop through every bit in `x`, stopping in the first most significant bit that is set. `i` is initialized to `1000000000000000000000000000`, and the loop keeps right shifting it until `x & i` evaluates to something that is not zero, at which point we found the first most significant bit that is `1`. At that point, taking `i`'s complement will yield the mask to turn off this bit in `x`, since `~i` is a number with every bit set to 1 except the only bit that was a `1` (which corresponds to the highest order bit in `x`). Thus, ANDing this with `x` gives you what you want.

The code is portable: it does not assume any particular representation, nor does it rely on the fact that `unsigned` is 32 or 64 bits.

**UPDATE**: I'm adding a more detailed explanation after reading your comment.

1st step - understanding what `x & (x-1)` does:

We have to consider two possibilities here:

- `x` ends with a 1 (`.......0011001`)
- `x` ends with a 0 (`.......0011000`)

In the first case, it is easy to see that `x-1` is just `x` with the rightmost bit set to 0. For example, `0011001 - 1 = 0011000`, so, effectively, `x & (x-1)` will just be `x-1`.

In the second case, it might be slightly harder to understand, but if the rightmost bit of `x` is a 0, then `x-1` will be `x` with every 0 bit switched to a 1 bit, starting on the least significant bits, until a 1 is found, which is turned into a 0.

Let me give you an example, because this can be tricky for someone new to this:

`1101011000 - 1 = 11101010111`

Why is that? Because the previous number of a binary number ending with a 0 is a binary number filled with one or more 1 bits in the rightmost positions. When we increment it, like `10101111101111 + 1`, we have to increment the next "free" position, i.e., the next 0 position, to turn it into a 1, and then all of the 1-bits to the right of that position are turned into 0. This is the way ANY base-n counting works, the only difference is that for base-2 you only have 0's and 1's.

Think about how base-10 counting works. When we run out of digits, the value wraps around and we add a new digit on the left side. What comes after `999`? Well, the counting resets again, with a new digit on the left, and the 9's wrap around to 0, and the result is `1000`. The same thing happens with binary arithmetic.

Think about the process of counting in binary; we just have 2 bits, 0 and 1:

- 0 (decimal 0)
- 1 (decimal 1 - now, we ran out of bits. For the next number, this 1 will be turned into a 0, and we need to add a new bit to the left)
- 10 (decimal 2)
- 11 (decimal 3 - the process is going to repeat again - we ran out of bits, so now those 2 bits will be turned into 0 and a new bit to the left must be added)
- 100 (decimal 4)
- 101 (decimal 5)
- 110 (the same process repeats again)
- 111
- ...

See how the pattern is exactly as I described?

Remember we are considering the 2nd case, where `x` ends with a 0. While comparing `x-1` with `x`, rightmost 0's on `x` are now 1's in `x-1`, and the rightmost 1 in `x` is now 0 in `x-1`. Thus, the only part of `x` that remains the same is that on the left of the 1 that was turned into a 0.

So, `x & (x-1)` will be the same as `x` until the position where the first rightmost 1 bit was. So now we can see that in both cases, `x & (x-1)` will in fact delete the rightmost 1 bit of `x`.

2nd step: What exactly is `~0U >> 1`?

The letter `U` stands for `unsigned`. In C, integer constants are of type `int` unless you specify it. Appending a `U` to an integer constant makes it unsigned. I used this because, as I mentioned earlier, it is implementation defined whether right shifting makes sign extension. The unary operator `~` is the complement operator, it grabs a number, and takes its complement: every 0 bit is turned into 1 and every 1 bit is turned into 0. So, ~0 is a number filled with 1's: `11111111111...`. Then I shift it right one position, so now we have: `01111111....`, and the expression for this is `~0U >> 1`. Finally, I take the complement of that, to get `100000....`, which in code is `~(~0U >> 1)`. This is just a portable way to get a number with the leftmost bit set to 1 and every other set to 0.

You can give a look at K&R chapter 2, more specifically, section 2.9. Starting on page 48, bitwise operators are presented. Exercise 2-9 challenges the reader to explain why `x & (x-1)` works. In case you don't know, K&R is a book describing the C programming language written by Kernighan and Ritchie, the creators of C. The book title is "The C Programming Language", I recommend you to get a copy of the second edition. Every good C programmer learned C from this book.

Comment: hi, could you give me some more explanation ? when you do `x-1` if `x` = 10100 : 20, does `x-1` = 10011 : 19 ? then `x & (x-1)` = 10000 : 16 ? also what means `~0U >> 1` ? I guess it's your 1000000000000000000000000000 but could provide me a link where I can get some explaination (or book, i can check at the lib). thx

Comment: @bobandhisgolemlvl5 I edited my answer with some more explanations. I hope I made it clear for you, I don't know how to explain it better. My advice: get a copy of K&R 2nd edition, read it, and make every exercise, you will learn a lot.

Comment: @bobandhisgolemlvl5 and yes, your example with x = 20 is correct.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to check first if there is more than one "1".

If a number has a single `1` in its binary representation then it is a number that can be represented in the form 2<sup>x</sup>. For example,

```
4     00000100   2^2  
32    00010000   2^5
```

So to check for single one, you can just check for this property.

If log<sub>2</sub> (*x*) is a whole number then it has single `1` in it's binary representation.

You can [calculate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3064939/177116) log<sub>2</sub> (*x*)

log<sub>2</sub> (*x*) = log<sub>*y*</sub> (*x*) / log<sub>*y*</sub> (2)

where *y* can be anything, which for standard log functions is either 10 or *e*.

Here is a solution

```
double logBase2 = log(num)/log(2);   
if (logBase2 != (int)logBase2) {

    int i = 7;
    for (;i >0 ; i--) {

        if (num & (1 << i)) {

            num &= ~(1 << i);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Logs? You can simply test `x != 0 && (x & (x - 1)) == 0` to see if `x` has exactly 1 bit set

Comment: No doubt your solution is succinct but IMHO logs logic is easier to remember and understand.