# Finding the log base 2 rounded up to integer the same as rounding up to power of two and finding the highest set bit?

Tags: c++, bit, logarithm

Similarly, value rounded down to power of two and finding the rightmost set bit is equivalent to log base 2 rounded down to integer. Is that correct?

I thought that that would work, for any number round up to a power of two and do what in C++ is countr_zero() or in MSVC is a bitscan function or on GCC is __builtin_ctz(). Would this work? And this must be way better than the log function which is (from my understanding) probably the slowest calculation a CPU can do.

Interestingly, doing it this way involves quite a few steps itself:

```
//Round up to power of 2
unsigned int v; // compute the next highest power of 2 of 32-bit v

v--;
v |= v >> 1;
v |= v >> 2;
v |= v >> 4;
v |= v >> 8;
v |= v >> 16;
v++;
```

While countr_zero looks like:

```
usize countr_zero(u64 x) {
  if (x == 0)
    return 64;
#ifdef __GNUC__
  return __builtin_ctzll(x);
#else
  constexpr std::array<usize, 64> table = {
      0,  1,  2,  7,  3,  13, 8,  27, 4,  33, 14, 36, 9,  49, 28, 19,
      5,  25, 34, 17, 15, 53, 37, 55, 10, 46, 50, 39, 29, 42, 20, 57,
      63, 6,  12, 26, 32, 35, 48, 18, 24, 16, 52, 54, 45, 38, 41, 56,
      62, 11, 31, 47, 23, 51, 44, 40, 61, 30, 22, 43, 60, 21, 59, 58};
  return table[(x & ~x + 1) * 0x218A7A392DD9ABF >> 58 & 0x3F];
#endif
}
```

But it still has to be better than calling log and converting to integer, right?

Comment: @harold and subtract from the  total number of bits?

Comment: [Minimum number of bits to represent a given `int`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21191307/995714), [Getting the index of the leftmost active bit in an integer instantly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47725337/995714)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [log2 for max int and long values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67559309/log2-for-max-int-and-long-values)

Answer (score 2):

Yes,

- rounding to the next lower power of two and taking the logarithm is equivalent as taking the floored logarithm, and
- rounding up to the next greater power of two and taking the logarithm is equivalent to taking the ceiled logarithm.

These equivalences are only true if we ignore the edge case of `log2(0.1)`, where `floor(log2(0.1))` is not the same as `log2(0)`.

Note that you can obtain the floored binary logarithm of any integer `x` using `std::bit_width(x) - 1`. The ceiled logarithm is also obtainable this way; you just need to increment if `x` is not a power of two.

> But it still has to be better than calling `log` and converting to integer, right?

It's not obvious that it would be slower. Floating point operations may have hardware support, and can be faster in principle. Especially `sqrt` is surprisingly fast. I am not aware of any architecture with a fast built-in logarithm instruction. The x87 instruction is relatively slow.

When in doubt, you should profile.

#### See Also

- [How can you quickly compute the integer logarithm for any base?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63411054/5740428)
- [Bit Twiddling Hacks by Sean Eron Anderson](https://graphics.stanford.edu/%7Eseander/bithacks.html)

Comment: It's in fact extremely common to have hardware support for `log2`. You need it for int-to-float conversion. The reason is that int-to-float has to represent the value v as a `sign(v), log2(v), abs(v)/log2(v)` triplet.

Comment: there are already `std::countl_zero`,  `std::bit_ceil` and `std::bit_floor` in the [`<bit>` header](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/bit) exactly for this which should be compiled to a single CPU instruction if possible and should be more efficient

Comment: @phuclv I've provided `std::bit_width` because you don't need to first subtract from the maximum number of bits. `std::bit_width` does that for you; you just need to subtract `1` to get the logarithm. This is a zero-overhead abstraction after compiler optimizations, because you're just doing `const - countl_zero(x) - const`, which is the optimizable to just `const - countl_zero(x)`. In other words, you're not adding any more CPU instructions. See also: https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/ddfa43933ebc9e6508f0df9e748a765a74e01809/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/bit#L371

Comment: Also [`std::bit_ceil` compiles to a number of instructions, not just one](https://godbolt.org/z/WEdjf471K). It's still an O(1) implementation though because it's backed by `lzcnt`, and beats the O(log n) implementation that OP is using.