# Bitwise concatenation of two numbers

Tags: c++, c, radix

I intend to write a function which accepts two numbers and concatenates their binary values such that:

> resultingNumber=(number1)|(number2)

Here i need ((number1) << num_bits_in_2) |(number2). i.e. number2 should occupy the lowest bits. Number1 should occupy the higher bits and should not overlap with bits of maxnumber2

```
func(number1, number2, maxnumber1, maxnumber2)
{
    long rem,i=1,binaryMaxNumber1=0,binaryMaxNumber2=0, lenNumber1=0, lenNumber2=0;
    do
    {
        rem=maxNumber1%2;
        binaryMaxNumber1=binaryMaxNumber1 + (i*rem);
        lenNumber1++;
        maxNumber1=maxNumber1/2;
        i=i*10;
    }while(maxNumber1>0);

    i=1;
    do
    {
        rem=maxNumber2%2;
        binaryMaxNumber2=binaryMaxNumber2 + (i*rem);
        lenNumber2++;
        maxNumber2=maxNumber2/2;
        i=i*10;
    }while(maxNumber2>0);

    unsigned resultingNumber=(number1<<lenNumber2)|(number2);
}
```

I wrote the above mentioned program in order to get the desired results. Is there any other way which is more efficient than this to achieve the same in C/c++. As I need to call this function again and again for very large numbers.

Comment: Can you give example inputs and outputs?

Comment: Is this a C question or a C++ question? There is no such language as "C/C++".

Comment: is `lenNumber` just going to be equal to position of `maxNumber`'s leftmost set bit? You don't even use `rem` and `binaryMaxNumber` either

Comment: `((number2) << num_bits_in_1) |(number1)` or am I missing something?

Comment: @NeilKirk Its vice versa: ((number1) << num_bits_in_2) |(number2). i.e. number2 should occupy the lowest bits. Number1 should occupy the highest bits but should not overlap with bits of maxnumber2

Comment: @Ben Yes I dont use it..therefore the code is inefficient but i need them in order to find the number of bits by which I should perform bit shift

Comment: C/C++ means i am ok with either c or C++

Comment: @user3809749  Your own comment appears to mostly satisfy the post `((number1) << num_bits_in_2) |(number2)`.  What else do you need?

Comment: @chux I just need this

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to write log base(2) in c/c++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3064926/how-to-write-log-base2-in-c-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your codes is correct your function can be rewritten like this:

```
unsigned long func( unsigned long number1, unsigned long number2, unsigned long , unsigned long maxnumber2)
{
    while( maxnumber2 ) {
        maxnumber2 >>= 1;
        number1 <<= 1;
    }
    return number1 | number2;
}
```

But if you use the same `maxnumber2` it would be better to count number of bits to shift outside of the function and pass that instead of maxnumber.

Comment: Better yet, if `maxnumber2` is constant, use a `static const int bitsnumber2`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [_BitScanReverse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbxyd7zd.aspx) intrinsic to quickly find the number of bits for `number2`.

```
long long func( long number1, long number2)
{
    unsigned long numBits = 0;
    if( _BitScanReverse(&numBits, (unsigned)number1))
    {
        return (long long)(number1<<numBits)|number2;
    }
    return (long long)number2;
}
```

Note that the size of the resulting number should be big enough to contain the other numbers.

Comment: number of bits in `maxnumber2` not `number2`. And where did OP say that this is (only) for MS VS?