# C - find size of initialized data in an integer variable

Tags: c

I need size of initialized data stored in an integer variable.

Suppose.

```
u32 var = 0x0; should return 0

u32 var = 0x12; should return 1

u32 var = 0x1234; should return 2

u32 var = 0x123456; should return 3

u32 var = 0x12345678; should return 4
```

Comment: Either count leading zero bits or just do four compares.

Comment: Do you really mean "initialized"? Because for a u32 to contain "0x12" the 3 most significant bytes had to be initialized to zeroes. If they weren't, you'd have 3 bytes of random garbage followed by u8 0x12.

Comment: Given that you want `0x123456` to yield `3`, what about `0x120056`? Do you want `2` (i.e. number of non-zero bytes) or `3` (which is the "leading zero" version)?

Comment: Whatever the `u32` type is, its data size will be the same regardless of the content.

Comment: And what have _you_ done to resolve this problem?

Comment: You need to come up with a much better description of your problem. Assuming `u32` is 4 bytes, all your examples initialize all 4 bytes of `var`; some of those bytes happen to be zeros. Describe the problem you're actually trying to solve. For `0xFF000000`, is the correct answer 1 or 4? And finally, why do you want this information; what are you going to do with it?

Answer (score 1):

A log2(x) will give you the exponent of a binary value. Some C implementations have this function already built-in. If not, there are some alternative here: [How to write log base(2) in c/c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3064926/how-to-write-log-base2-in-c-c)

The resulting exponent can be divided and rounded in order to give the values you need.

A first attempt (untested) is:

```
int byteCount(const int x) 
{
  if (x == 0) return 0;  /* Avoid error */
  return (int)trunc((log10(x)/log10(2))/8+1);
}
```

**UPDATE**:
It seems my code is being taken literally. Here is an optimized version:

```
int byteCount(const u32 x) 
{
  if (x == 0) return 0;  /* Avoid error */
  return (int)trunc((log10(x)/0.301029995663981)/8+1);
}
```

Comment: where should I find this log2(x) function I couldn't find it on math.h

Comment: If you don't have it in your library, then implement it as suggested in the link I provided. Basically it is: log2(x) = log10(x) / log10(2)

Comment: Since OP is using `u32`, I'd adjust the argument to use that instead of `int` as, otherwise, it doesn't work too well if the MSB is set (e.g. `0x80000000`). Unless it's an OP requirement, using floating point for this is a bit slow. I posted an answer using a different function with a test program that compares yours and mine for correctness and speed.

Comment: My code is just a draft, of course the input value can be changed to u32. Regarding the floating point, it is slow because it is not optimized. Just try to change `log10(2)` with a constant value.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to count number of non-zero bytes?

```
u8 countNonZeroBytes(u32 n) {
    u8 result = n == 0 ? 0 : 1;
    while (n >> 8 != 0) {
        result++;
        n = n >> 8;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Not exactly, I need a c library function to do this functionality.

Comment: @Andrew The solution is not correct for n = 0x12 (1 byte).

Comment: There is no c library function to do this.

Comment: @user3423907 there is no such standard library function in pure C. So, accept one of provided solutions as answer (that are not buggy or terribly inefficient)

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the answer as per your requirement.

```
u8 CountNonZeroBytes(u32 n) {
    u32 mask = 0xFF;
    u8 i, result = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(n); i++) {
        if (mask & n)
            result++;
        mask = mask << 8;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version of the "leading zeroes" approach to `log2` that doesn't use floating point. The optimizer will do loop unrolling, so it's equivalent to the "four compare" version. It is *4x* faster than the floating point version.

```
u32
bytecnt(u32 val)
{
    int bitno;
    u32 msk;
    u32 bycnt;

    bycnt = 0;
    for (bitno = 24;  bitno >= 0;  bitno -= 8) {
        msk = 0xFF << bitno;
        if (val & msk) {
            bycnt = bitno / 8;
            bycnt += 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    return bycnt;
}
```

Here is a test program that compares the two algorithms [Note that I'm using Jaime's floating point version for comparison]:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef unsigned int u32;

#define RATIO \
    do { \
        if (tvslow > tvfast) \
            ratio = tvslow / tvfast; \
        else \
            ratio = tvfast / tvslow; \
        printf("%.3fx\n",ratio); \
    } while (0)

int opt_f;

// _tvgetf -- get timestamp
double
_tvgetf(void)
{
    struct timespec ts;
    double val;

#if 1
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME,&ts);
#else
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW,&ts);
#endif

    val = ts.tv_nsec;
    val /= 1e9;
    val += ts.tv_sec;

    return val;
}

u32
bytecnt(u32 val)
{
    int bitno;
    u32 msk;
    u32 bycnt;

    bycnt = 0;
    for (bitno = 24;  bitno >= 0;  bitno -= 8) {
        msk = 0xFF << bitno;
        if (val & msk) {
            bycnt = bitno / 8;
            bycnt += 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    return bycnt;
}

u32
bytecnt2(u32 val)
{
    u32 bycnt;

    do {
        if (val & (0xFF << 24)) {
            bycnt = 4;
            break;
        }

        if (val & (0xFF << 16)) {
            bycnt = 3;
            break;
        }

        if (val & (0xFF << 8)) {
            bycnt = 2;
            break;
        }

        if (val & (0xFF << 0)) {
            bycnt = 1;
            break;
        }

        bycnt = 0;
    } while (0);

    return bycnt;
}

int byteCount(const int x)
{
  if (x == 0) return 0;  /* Avoid error */
  return (int)trunc((log10(x)/log10(2))/8+1);
}

u32 byteCount2(u32 x)
{
  if (x == 0) return 0;  /* Avoid error */
  return (u32)trunc((log10(x)/log10(2))/8+1);
}

static double l2 = 0;
u32 byteCount3(u32 x)
{
  if (x == 0) return 0;  /* Avoid error */
  return (u32)trunc((log10(x)/l2)/8+1);
}

u32 byteCount4(u32 x)
{
  if (x == 0) return 0;  /* Avoid error */
  return (u32)trunc((log10(x)/0.301029995663981)/8+1);
}

void
test(u32 val)
{
    u32 bicnt;
    u32 lgcnt;

    bicnt = bytecnt(val);
    lgcnt = byteCount2(val);

    if (bicnt != lgcnt) {
        printf("%8.8X: bicnt=%8.8X lgcnt=%8.8X\n",
            val,bicnt,lgcnt);
        exit(1);
    }
}

double
timeit(u32 (*proc)(u32),const char *who)
{
    double tvbeg;
    double tvdif;
    double tvper;
    int trycnt;
    int trymax;
    u32 val;

    trymax = 1000000;
    trymax *= 10;

    tvbeg = _tvgetf();

    for (trycnt = 1;  trycnt < trymax;  ++trycnt) {
        for (val = 1;  val != 0;  val <<= 1)
            proc(val);
    }

    tvdif = _tvgetf();
    tvdif -= tvbeg;
    tvper = tvdif;
    tvper /= trymax;
    tvper /= 32;
    printf("%.9f %.9f -- %s\n",tvdif,tvper,who);

    return tvdif;
}

int
main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    char *cp;
    u32 val;
    double tvfast;
    double tvslow;
    double ratio;

    --argc;
    ++argv;

    l2 = log10(2);

    for (;  argc > 0;  --argc, ++argv) {
        cp = *argv;
        if (*cp != '-')
            break;

        switch (cp[1]) {
        case 'f':
            opt_f = 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    // do quick validity test
    printf("quick validity test ...\n");
    test(0);
    for (val = 1;  val != 0;  val <<= 1)
        test(val);

    // speed tests
    printf("speed tests ...\n");
    tvfast = timeit(bytecnt2,"bytecnt2");
    tvslow = timeit(bytecnt,"bytecnt");
    RATIO;
    tvslow = timeit(byteCount2,"byteCount2");
    RATIO;
    tvslow = timeit(byteCount3,"byteCount3");
    RATIO;
    tvslow = timeit(byteCount4,"byteCount4");
    RATIO;

    // do full validity test
    if (opt_f) {
        for (val = 1;  val != 0;  ++val)
            test(val);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the test output:

```
quick validity test ...
speed tests ...
1.180300474 0.000000004 -- bytecnt2
1.363260031 0.000000004 -- bytecnt
1.155x
6.759670734 0.000000021 -- byteCount2
5.727x
6.653460503 0.000000021 -- byteCount3
5.637x
6.636421680 0.000000021 -- byteCount4
5.623x
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> my byteCount proposal is not optimized, for the sake of clarity. For example, you can convert log10(2) into a constant. I think that would have a noticeable increase of performance.

I've updated the test program to incorporate the changes.

But, the optimizer had *already* eliminated the `log10(2)` in your original code (i.e. only *one* call to `log10`), so hand coding it had little to no effect.

Several others did similar loop implementations for number of zero bytes [which I don't believe is what OP wanted, based on the "sizeof" phrase].

It turns out that the fastest version is also the simplest, most boring, and [IMO] most straightforward. This is something I added: `bytecnt2`, which is the "four compares" suggested by Paul R.

Doing floating point would be fine with better [or comparable] performance. I'd give it a pass even at 2x [FYI, before getting the results, I assumed that they *would* be ballpark (e.g. within 10%)].

But, the F.P. implementation is also *less* straightforward for OP's intended result.

IMO, something that is 4x slower [and more complicated] is a red flag. Not just tweaking, but indicates the approach is incorrect. Taking an int and converting it into a float [and back again], using some relatively heavyweight functions, for something that simple bit shifting/masking will accomplish.

Comment: Craig, my byteCount proposal is not optimized, for the sake of clarity. For example, you can convert log10(2) into a constant. I think that would have a noticeable increase of performance.

Comment: @Jaime I've updated my answer with your changes and test results.

Comment: Craig, there is no "incorrect" approach whenever you get the desired result. It is a compromise between readability and performance. For a mathematician, my approach may be clearer than a for-loop. Of course performance matters for most cases, unless the processing time (microseconds) is marginal within a wider process (i.e. seconds).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind use gcc extensions, this is a very good solution:

*by the way you should be more clear in your question. Your terminology is confusing. Both "size" and "initialized" are used outside their established meaning.*

Extra extra safe/portable: (probably not needed):

```
size_t leading_zeroes(uint32_t v)
{
  if (v == 0) // __builtin_clz is undefined for 0
    return sizeof(uint32_t) * CHAR_BIT;
  return __builtin_clz(v);
}

size_t trailing_bytes(uint32_t v)
{
  return sizeof(uint32_t) - leading_zeroes(v) / CHAR_BIT;
}
```

Simpler version:

```
size_t leading_zeroes(uint32_t v)
{
  if (v == 0) // __builtin_clz is undefined for 0
    return 32;
  return __builtin_clz(v);
}

size_t trailing_bytes(uint32_t v)
{
  return 4 - leading_zeroes(v) / 8;
}
```