# Logarithm base 2 in C language

Tags: c, logarithm

Please, can someone help me with how to calculate a simple log2 in C? I tried with this code, but it does not work:

```
printf( "log( %f ) = %f\n", x, log2(x) );
```

Comment: Explain *"does not work"*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write log base(2) in c/c++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3064926/how-to-write-log-base2-in-c-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also create a helper function which converts to any log base you wish:

Something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

double 
my_log(double x, int base) { 
    return log(x) / log(base); 
} 

int 
main(void) {
    double x = 42.0;

    printf("log(%f) = %f\n", x, my_log(x, 2));

    return 0;
}
```

Compiled with:

```
gcc -Wall -o logprog logprog.c -lm
```

Output:

```
log(42.000000) = 5.392317
```

Answer (score 5):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    double x = 42.0;

    printf( "log( %f ) = %f\n", x, log2(x) );

    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT

```
% ./a.out
log( 42.000000 ) = 5.392317
%
```

Comment: So why does OP's code not work?

Comment: @Rightleg Probably missing `<math.h>` which means that the return value incorrectly defaults to `int`.

Comment: He also might need to compile with `-lm`, depending which version of `gcc` he is using.