# Number of unset bit left of most significant set bit?

Tags: c#, c++, c, 64-bit, bit-manipulation

Assuming the 64bit integer `0x000000000000FFFF` which would be represented as

```
00000000 00000000  00000000 00000000
00000000 00000000 >11111111 11111111
```

How do I find the amount of unset bits to the left of the most significant set bit (the one marked with >) ?

Comment: Are you interested in C, C# or C++? The theory is the same but the languages are different.

Comment: Since I assumed there some bit-twiddling magic to do this and it looks pretty much the same in all languages it doesn't really matter.

Comment: Google "fxtbook.pdf", chapter 1.6.1

Comment: There are a number of shortcuts you can take if this value is always of the pattern 0*1* (all 0s, followed by all 1s), is this the case?

Comment: @jkerian Yes ... then it's just 64 - bitcount(value). Search for popcount or Debruijn for efficient ways to count bits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// clear all bits except the lowest set bit
x &= -x;     

// if x==0, add 0, otherwise add x - 1. 
// This sets all bits below the one set above to 1.
x+= (-(x==0))&(x - 1);

return 64 - count_bits_set(x);
```

Where `count_bits_set` is the fastest version of counting bits you can find. See https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#CountBitsSetParallel for various bit counting techniques.

Comment: As it stands, doesn't the first line clear all bits except the _lowest_ set one?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen, ah, so it does! I'm not sure why I answered it this way in retrospect.

Comment: -1 How did this get accepted? It's completely wrong. First, it tries to compute the number of bit positions above the lowest bit set, which is not what was asked for. Second, the condition in the second line is backwards. The desired effect of the first two lines can be achieved with `if (x) x ^= x-1` ... but as long as a test is being done, one might as well do `if (!x) return ...`, and then 0 can be mapped into anything. (Better yet, make this function undefined for 0 and let the caller deal with it.)

Answer (score 6):

In straight C (long long are 64 bit on my setup), taken from similar Java implementations:  (updated after a little more reading on Hamming weight)

A little more explanation:  The top part just sets all bit to the right of the most significant 1, and then negates it.  (i.e. all the 0's to the 'left' of the most significant 1 are now 1's and everything else is 0).

Then I used a [Hamming Weight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_weight) implementation to count the bits.

```
unsigned long long i = 0x0000000000000000LLU;

i |= i >> 1;
i |= i >> 2;
i |= i >> 4;
i |= i >> 8;
i |= i >> 16;
i |= i >> 32;
// Highest bit in input and all lower bits are now set. Invert to set the bits to count.
i=~i;

i -= (i >> 1) & 0x5555555555555555LLU; // each 2 bits now contains a count
i = (i & 0x3333333333333333LLU) + ((i >> 2) & 0x3333333333333333LLU); // each 4 bits now contains a count
i = (i + (i >> 4)) & 0x0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0fLLU; // each 8 bits now contains a count 
i *= 0x0101010101010101LLU; // add each byte to all the bytes above it
i >>= 56; // the number of bits

printf("Leading 0's = %lld\n", i);
```

I'd be curious to see how this was efficiency wise.  Tested it with several values though and it seems to work.

Answer (score 4):

Based on: http://www.hackersdelight.org/HDcode/nlz.c.txt

```
template<typename T> int clz(T v) {int n=sizeof(T)*8;int c=n;while (n){n>>=1;if (v>>n) c-=n,v>>=n;}return c-v;}
```

If you'd like a version that allows you to keep your lunch down, here you go:

```
int clz(uint64_t v) {
    int n=64,c=64;
    while (n) {
        n>>=1;
        if (v>>n) c-=n,v>>=n;
    }
    return c-v;
}
```

As you'll see, you can save cycles on this by careful analysis of the assembler, but the strategy here is not a terrible one. The while loop will operate Lg[64]=6 times; each time it will convert the problem into one of counting the number of leading bits on an integer of half the size.
The if statement inside the while loop asks the question: "can i represent this integer in half as many bits", or analogously, "if i cut this in half, have i lost it?". After the if() payload completes, our number will always be in the lowest n bits.
At the final stage, v is either 0 or 1, and this completes the calculation correctly.

Answer (score 2):

If you are dealing with unsigned integers, you could do this:

```
#include <math.h>
int numunset(uint64_t number)
{
    int nbits = sizeof(uint64_t)*8;
    if(number == 0)
        return nbits;
    int first_set = floor(log2(number));
    return nbits - first_set - 1;
}
```

I don't know how it will compare in performance to the loop and count methods that have already been offered because log2() could be expensive.

**Edit**:

This could cause some problems with high-valued integers since the `log2()` function is casting to `double` and some numerical issues may arise.  You could use the `log2l()` function that works with `long double`.  A better solution would be to use an integer `log2()` function as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/994593/how-to-do-an-integer-log2-in-c).

Comment: Oh yes `log2` is damn expensive! I've even forgotten about this possibility at all. I don't know how such things are implemented in the processor FPU, however calculating any non-arithmetic function usually leads to calculating some series sum. I believe such a thing takes a lot of CPU cycles.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understood the problem correctly. I think you have a 64bit value and want to find the number of leading zeros in it.

One way would be to find the most significant bit and simply subtract its position from 63 (assuming lowest bit is bit 0). You can find out the most significant bit by testing whether a bit is set from within a loop over all 64 bits.

Another way might be to use the (non-standard) `__builtin_clz` in gcc.

Answer (score 1):

<s>Same idea as [user470379's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4097257/number-of-unset-bit-left-of-most-significant-set-bit/4097289#4097289), but counting down ...</s>
Assume all 64 bits are unset. While value is larger than 0 keep shifting the value right and decrementing number of unset bits:

```
/* untested */
int countunsetbits(uint64_t val) {
    int x = 64;
    while (val) { x--; val >>= 1; }
    return x;
}
```

Comment: Don't do it this way, please. This while() loop will execute 64 times. You can do this in 6 loop iterations, since you can binary partition the problem. See my answer, based on a Hacker's Delight implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the binary search idea. However two points are important here:

1. The range of valid answers to your question is from 0  to 64 **inclusive**. In other words - there may be **65** different answers to the question. I think (almost sure) all who posted the "binary search" solution missed this point, hence they'll get wrong answer for either zero or a number with the MSB bit on.
2. If speed is critical - you may want to avoid the loop. There's an elegant way to achieve this using templates.

The following template stuff finds the MSB correctly of any **unsigned** type variable.

```
// helper
template <int bits, typename T>
bool IsBitReached(T x)
{
    const T cmp = T(1) << (bits ? (bits-1) : 0);
    return (x >= cmp);
}

template <int bits, typename T>
int FindMsbInternal(T x)
{
    if (!bits)
        return 0;

    int ret;
    if (IsBitReached<bits>(x))
    {
        ret = bits;
        x >>= bits;
    } else
        ret = 0;

    return ret + FindMsbInternal<bits/2, T>(x);
}

// Main routine
template <typename T>
int FindMsb(T x)
{
    const int bits = sizeof(T) * 8;
    if (IsBitReached<bits>(x))
        return bits;

    return FindMsbInternal<bits/2>(x);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, pretty trivial to update as you need for other sizes...

```
int bits_left(unsigned long long value)
{
  static unsigned long long mask = 0x8000000000000000;
  int c = 64;
  // doh
  if (value == 0)
    return c;

  // check byte by byte to see what has been set
  if (value & 0xFF00000000000000)
    c = 0;
  else if (value & 0x00FF000000000000)
    c = 8;
  else if (value & 0x0000FF0000000000)
    c = 16;
  else if (value & 0x000000FF00000000)
    c = 24;
  else if (value & 0x00000000FF000000)
    c = 32;
  else if (value & 0x0000000000FF0000)
    c = 40;
  else if (value & 0x000000000000FF00)
    c = 48;
  else if (value & 0x00000000000000FF)
    c = 56;

  // skip
  value <<= c;

  while(!(value & mask))
  {
    value <<= 1;
    c++;
  }

  return c;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
int countBits(int value)
{
    int result = sizeof(value) * CHAR_BITS;  // should be 64

    while(value != 0)
    {
        --result;
        value = value >> 1; // Remove bottom bits until all 1 are gone.
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use log base 2 to get you the most significant digit which is 1.

```
log(2) = 1, meaning 0b10 -> 1
log(4) = 2, 5-7 => 2.xx, or 0b100 -> 2
log(8) = 3, 9-15 => 3.xx, 0b1000 -> 3
log(16) = 4 you get the idea
```

and so on...
The numbers in between become fractions of the log result. So typecasting the value to an int gives you the most significant digit.

Once you get this number, say b, the simple 64 - n will be the answer.

```
function get_pos_msd(int n){
    return int(log2(n))
}

last_zero = 64 - get_pos_msd(n)
```