# Picking the odd number out

Tags: c

I want to write a method that returns the last odd position available that has not been removed. For example

---

`Say the number inputted to function is 5`
`Then we can number as follows 1,2,3,4,5`

---

`After first pass, numbers left are - 2,4. 1,3,5 have been removed
After second pass - 2 has been removed and so we are left with 4`

---

`The function should return 4`. In my method, I create an array of n numbers. Each element may either have a value 0 or 1, 0 representing that element not being removed and 1 being removed.My code is

---

```
int findposition(int n)
{
int barr[n];
int count=0,i,begIndex=0;

for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    barr[i]=0;

while(n!=count+1)
{
    for(i=begIndex;i<n;i=i+2)
    {
        barr[i]=1;
    }


    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(barr[i]==0)
            begIndex=i;
    }

}

return (begIndex+1);
}
```

---

The above function compiles successfully, but does not print anything when called from main method. Also, I think my approach is a bit clumsy. Can there be a more neater way to do this.

Comment: What it should return is no use. Why is the two removed? Why are the odd number's removed? Programming has to be general, not specific.

Comment: `while(n!=count+1)` will loop endlessly unless the function is passed in `1`, in which case it wouldn't execute at all.

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, the solution boils down to finding the most significant bit of the input number. There are a few bit twiddling hacks to achieve this if you google for it.

Comment: Linuxios: Do you mean that I should take an input form the user and remove evry `k`th element until we reach the last element.

Comment: Follow up my comment from before: http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerLog

Comment: This sounds alot like homework. As do many of your other questions.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, the solution boils down to finding the most significant bit of the input number. This is simply [Josephus problem with k = 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus_problem#k.3D2).

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at the indices of the removed objects in the binary positional notation, you'll find out that in the first step you remove all the numbers which have a 1 as the last digit. This leaves us with numbers of form xxxx0, where xxxx are all binary digits in some range. So you will have like **001** 0, **010** 0, **011** 0, **100** 0. It's obvious that the second step removes all the numbers that have the suffix 10 and you'll end up with **01** 00, **10** 00, **11** 00 etc.

Apparently the last number standing is the one having the most trailing zeroes.

Comment: And to take this one step further, this number is equivalent to the input number's MSB with all other bits set to zero.  That can be done as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/994709), which would be a hilarious response to this (presumably) homework problem.  Other students would be busy learning the semantics of loops, while this student turns in `return (1 << __builtin_clz(n));`.  Gets low grade because this doesn't work on some compilers.