# How can I do an integer log2() in Fortran?

Tags: performance, fortran, bit-manipulation, fortran90, logarithm

An obvious way to do this would be the following:

```
integer function log2_i(val) result(res)
    implicit none
    integer, intent(IN) :: val

    if (val<0) then
        print *, "ERROR in log2_i(): val cannot be negative."
    else if (val==0) then
        print *, "ERROR in log2_i(): todo: return the integer equivalent of (-inf)..."
    else if (val==1) then
        res = 0
    else
        res = FLOOR( LOG(val+0.0d0)/LOG(2.0d0) )
    endif
end function log2_i
```

Is there a better way using Fortran's bitshifting operators?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/994593/how-to-do-an-integer-log2-in-c) is almost the same, but uses unsigned integers. Unfortunately, the sign bit would prohibit using the same algorithm.

Comment: RSHIFT on a non-negative operand is equivalent to a logical right shift, so I don't see any problem

Comment: Take a look at the standard function `ILEN`, it should be very close to what you need (+/- 1).

Comment: @njuffa That's the HPF intrinsic, rather a Fortran one, though? So it may not be widely supported.

Comment: @francescalus Good point. I don't use Fortran often and thought that this is part of Fortran 2003, but maybe it is an HPF extension only. It has been available with all the Fortran compilers I have used in recent years, so if it is an extension it seems to be a common one (may need to check compiler flag settings for enabling HPF features).

Comment: There is no `ILEN` in gfortran https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Intrinsic-Procedures.html

Comment: you could use `btest` in a loop.

Answer (score 5):

As @harold mentioned, this shouldn't be a problem: since the logarithm is only defined for positive numbers, the sign bit is always zero (see the corresponding [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations)). Therefore, the algorithm in the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/994593/how-to-do-an-integer-log2-in-c) can be directly ported to Fortran (2008 Standard):

```
module mod_test
contains
  function ilog2_b(val ) result( res )
    integer, intent(in) :: val
    integer             :: res
    integer             :: tmp

    res = -1 
    ! Negativ values not allowed
    if ( val < 1 ) return

    tmp = val
    do while (tmp > 0)
      res = res + 1
      tmp = shiftr( tmp, 1 )
    enddo
  end function
end module

program test
  use mod_test
  print *,'Bitshifting: ', ilog2_b(12345)
  print *,'Formula:     ', floor( log(real(12345) ) / log(2.) )
end program
```

---

This is a solution based on the Fortran 95 intrinsic [`BTEST`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/BTEST.html#BTEST) as suggested by @agentp:

```
module mod_test
contains
  function ilog2_b2(val ) result( res )
    integer, intent(in) :: val
    integer             :: res
    integer             :: i

    res = -1 
    ! Negativ values not allowed
    if ( val < 1 ) return
    do i=bit_size(val)-1,0,-1
      if ( btest(val, i) ) then
        res = i
        return
      endif
    enddo

  end function
end module

program test
  use mod_test
  print *,'Testing bits:', ilog2_b2(123456)
  print *,'Formula:     ', floor( log(real(123456) ) / log(2.) )
end program
```

Thanks to @IanH to point me towards [`bit_size`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/BIT_005fSIZE.html)... 
If your compiler supports [`shiftr`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/SHIFTR.html#SHIFTR), I would use the first variant instead.

---

@IanH mentioned yet another method using [`leadz`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/LEADZ.html), which is a Fortran 2008 feature:

```
module mod_test
contains
  function ilog2_b3(val ) result( res )
    integer, intent(in) :: val
    integer             :: res

    res = -1 
    ! Negativ values not allowed
    if ( val < 1 ) return

    res = bit_size(val)-leadz(val)-1
  end function
end module

program test
  use mod_test
  print *,'Testing bits:', ilog2_b3(123456)
  print *,'Formula:     ', floor( log(real(123456) ) / log(2.) )
end program
```