# quickly find the integer part of the base 2 logarithm

Tags: c++, c, floating-point, ieee-754

What is an efficient method to calculate the integer part of the base 2 logarithm of a floating point number? Something like

```
N = ceil( log2( f ))
```

or

```
N = floor( log2( f ))
```

for floating point f. I guess this is possible to realize very efficiently somehow as one probably only needs access to the floating point exponent.

EDIT2: I am not primarily interested in *exactness*. I could tolerate an error of +-1. I listed the two variants just as an example because one might be computationally cheaper than the other (but I dont know).

I need this for accuracy control of an algorithm where the parameter f is some tolerance and the log is needed to control the number of terms. Accurate calculation of the log is not important.

EDIT: this is not a duplicate of other the many other questions asking for the log2 of an *integer* argument (e.g. [How to do an integer log2() in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/994593/how-to-do-an-integer-log2-in-c)) . This here is about *floating point* argument and a completely different story. Specifically I need it for f < 1, which is not possible at all with the integer methods

Comment: With modern CPUs with built-in FPUs, that implement logarithmic operations in hardware, I would be surprised if a hand-crafted implementation would beat the direct `floor(log2(f))` approach.

Comment: No duplicate. my question is about log2 of a floating point number. Not the log2 of an integer.

Comment: Seeing as the log of a number less than 1 is negative, it's your call whether that should be rounded up or down.

Comment: Can't you just extract the exponent and subtract 127 (single precision) or 1023 (double precision)?

Comment: @WeatherVane: I would be happy with either version...

Comment: @Fanael: yes, perhaps.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The standard library function [`frexp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/frexp) does exactly that: it decomposes a double into an integer exponent and a normalized mantissa.

If you are content with the floor of the logarithm, rather than rounding the logarithm to the nearest integer, you are probably better off with the newer standard library function [`ilogb`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/ilogb).

Note that these two functions treat zeros and infinities differently, so they are not quite interchangeable.

Comment: Thanks, this is a solution I was looking for. However, I think the function ilogb might be a slightly better fit. Thanks for pointing me to it.

Comment: @andreas: you are probably right. I guess I am showing my age :-)

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by rici, who pointed me to frexp, I think I found the answer. In C99 and recent C++ we have the function [ilogb](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/ilogb) which does exactly that what I need

```
int ilogb( float arg );
int ilogb( double arg );
```

and is equivalent to

```
(int)logb( arg )
```

It returns one less than frexp. So the frexp result corresponds to

```
floor(log2(arg)+1
```

and ilogb(arg) to

```
floor(log2(arg))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a horrible hack which extracts the exponent from the little-endian `float` although I make no guarantee about portability, etc.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    float f;
    unsigned i;
    unsigned *ip = (unsigned*)&f;

    printf("Enter a float: ");
    scanf("%f", &f);
    i = *ip;
    i = (i >> 23) & 0xFF;
    i -= 127;
    printf("%f %d\n", f, (int)i);
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
Enter a float: 0.125
0.125000 -3
```

Comment: Note that you shouldn't use pointer dereferencing for type-punning, as it is undefined behaviour (most compilers will throw a warning with `-Wall`). Unions should be used instead.

Comment: @Simon: I thought that reading a **different** type from a union than you wrote into it is also UB. Am I wrong?

Comment: @WaetherVane: your hack probably works equally well for big-endian. It only won't work if floats and integers have different endianness.

Comment: No, it's been defined since C99 (though technically not C++): http://stackoverflow.com/a/25672839/392585

Comment: Note: This does not return the correct answer for sub-normal values: `f < FLT_MIN`

Comment: @chux I did say it was horrible. I don't expect any votes but mybad I should at least have used a union.