# Library Function for logx(n)

Tags: c++

I want to calculate the value of ***log x(n)*** where **x** is base and **n** is any integer. Is there any library function in c++ to do the operation? Or i need to do it manually? If I need to do it manually how can i do that?
I have tried to do like that but it says "log x was not declared".

```
int x,n;
cin>>x>>n;
cout<<logx(n);
```

[image]

x=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8........ and
n= Any positive integer.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm see Change of base

Comment: `log(n) / log(x)`? Fore instance `log10(n) == log(n) / log(10)`

Comment: logx(n) here x is base and n is any integer.

Comment: btw your code looks a bit odd. How is the compiler supposed to know what is the value of `x` from this call alone :`logx(n)` ? If such a function exists it would need to take 2 arguments

Comment: yeah. it was my question. if there any function exist? I just give what i tried to do. i know it is wrong. i just want to what is correct. thanks

Comment: If you know its wrong, why include a really big screenshot of it?

Comment: sorry. i thought it is a site of finding the solve of a given problem. But all i see is arguing for the style of the post.
// i gave the screen shot because stack overflow didn't allowed me to give a post without a proof of doing some thing.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your image of text [isn't very helpful](//meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086).  It can't be read aloud or copied into an editor, and it doesn't index very well, meaning that other users with the same problem are less likely to find the answer here.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any library function in c++ to do the operation?

There is no such function in the standard library. However, it is easy to implement and therefore an implementation may exist in another library.

> Or i need to do it manually?

You *can* do it manually.

> If I need to do it manually how can i do that?

Using the magic of maths. The following equivalence makes the implementation easy, using the natural logarithm function that is provided by the C++ standard library.

> log<sub>b</sub>(x) = log<sub>e</sub>(x) / log<sub>e</sub>(b)

Where `x` is any number greater than 0, log<sub>b</sub> is logarithm in base `b`, and log<sub>e</sub> is the natural logarithm.

> I have tried to do like that but it says "log x was not declared".

That is a likely result of trying to guess a name of a function. I would recommend to instead check the reference or a book for what functions are available.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @Hafiz If this solved your question don't forget to accept.

Answer (score 3):

You will have to change the base manually. C++ provides [these logarithmic functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math#Exponential_functions):

- [`log`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/log) - base *e*
- [`log10`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/log10) - base *10*
- [`log2`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/log2) - base *2*
- [`log1p`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/log1p) - also uses base *e*

You can use the [Change of Base](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Change_of_base) trick to find your value, because of optimizations you'll want to use `log2` to do this.

So for example if you want to do log<sub>13</sub>(*42*) you could do:

```
log2(42) / log2(13)
```

Comment: Yeah. i got my answer. Thanks :)

Comment: Can you explain why you would use `log2()` rather than `log()` to do the change of base?  Is one implemented in hardware and the other in software on some platforms?  (If so, which platforms?)

Comment: @TobySpeight Since all the numbers that we work with are stored in base *2* on the computer, this is as simple as getting the position of the Most-Significant-Bit. That's a single cycle instruction: http://stackoverflow.com/a/994709/2642059

Comment: Sorry, I forgot this was all in integers - when I see mathematical functions, I tend to assume floating-point inputs of some kind.  I should read the question more carefully!