# log2 calculation gives wrong result in cpp

Tags: c++, floating-point, precision

both visual studio 2015 and gcc4.8 gives wrong result when calculating the log2 value of numbers greater than 49 ones.

```
double log2_49_ones = log2(0x1FFFFFFFFFFFF); // result is 49 - should be 48
double log2_48_ones = log2(0xFFFFFFFFFFFF); // result is 47 - correct result
```

Any idea if it is a bug ?

Comment: [`log2()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/log2) is supposed to take `double` values?

Comment: `std::log2` does not return an integer value see: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/log2 and as integer arguments are cast to double you are probably loosing precision.

Comment: this will also get bad value : double log2_49_ones = log2(0x1FFFFFFFFFFFF);

Comment: @OrDavidi As seen [here](http://ideone.com/yeVdIZ), `log2(0xFFFFFFFFFFFF);` returns 48, not 47, as you claim, which is correct, since `0xFFFFFFFFFFFF` is 2 to the 48 power. So, there's no surprise that `log2(0x1FFFFFFFFFFFF)` returns 49, since the value is 2 to the 49th power. Your expectations are wrong.

Comment: Java's math library [talks about](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) precision issues explicitly. Irrational functions like `log2()` are not guaranteed to produce the correctly rounded result, but may have an error of a few ULPs.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius a number with so many bits set is definitely not any power of two

Comment: As was mentioned by @AlgirdasPreidžius you expectations are wrong. Please check result of `std::pow (2, 49) - 0x1FFFFFFFFFFFF`, and `std::pow (2, 48) - 0x1FFFFFFFFFFFF`.

Comment: @harold: It is obvious that `0x1FFFFFFFFFFFF` is actually `pow(2, 49) - 1`, so the `log2()` value should be ever so slightly below `49.0`, and is probably rounded to `49.0` on output. Similar arguments for the other value.

Answer (score 2):

[`log2()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/log2/) takes a float/double number as a parameter, thus you are probably losing precision during the implicit casting.

You could use this trick:

```
unsigned int number = 59029; // example
int targetlevel = 0;
while (number >>= 1) ++targetlevel;
```

courtesy of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/994623/2411320).

Comment: [`log2`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/log2) also takes `long double` as an argument, where the numbers that OP is passing, fits without a precision loss.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius But the spec says that integral arguments are cast to double, not long double. see case (4): http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/log2

Answer (score 0):

The same floating point formats are used in multiple languages, and so this can be a generic problem. In Javascript in Chrome 58 for Windows, for example, I see the same results as you.

```
Math.log2(0x1FFFFFFFFFFFF) 
49 // this really is 49, i.e. if you subtract 49, it is 0
Math.log2(0xFFFFFFFFFFFF) 
47.99999999999999 // This would be 47 if put into an int
```

Let's not call this a bug: it is working near the limits of the capabilities of the floating point format and/or the software libraries.

If you want the correct answer up to about 2^53, then for largish numbers you can do some integer division, so that log2 can stay operating in its comfortable range. In Javascript (sorry! don't kill me please), for example

```
function betterLog2 (x) {
    if (x<2**32){
        return Math.log2(x)
    } else { 
        return 32 + Math.log2(parseInt(x/(2**32)))
    }
}
```

It seems to give correct answers for integers up to 2^53-1.

The same principle should work in any language and implementation. I doubt any language implementation would have a library that rounds up log 2 for values under 2**32.

Hope it helps 8-)

Comment: This is question about C++, not Javascript.

Comment: Both languages might use the same floating-point math libraries. FP issues can often be reproduced in multiple languages, such as the classic `0.1 + 0.2 != 0.3` problem

Comment: Thanks Nayuki! Yes, for me in Javascript 0.1+0.2 gives
0.30000000000000004. Many languages, under the hood, are using https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point. Excellent library but we just need to be aware of the limitations, and the value of this awareness transcends individual programming languages.

Comment: @Eureka: IEEE floating point is not a library, it is a standard, which is (or is claimed to be) implemented, as well as possible, by many different libraries. It is possible that Javascript internally uses a C or C++ runtime library, but if it does, it is not certain which one. Actually, it may depend on the browser, I guess.

Comment: @Rudy Velthuis: Thank you for clarifying this and sorry for my sloppy thinking. I have corrected my answer. I've left my incorrectly-worded comment above, so that people can understand your comment.