# Min-Max Heap, how to get level of node from given index in O(1)?

Tags: c, data-structures, binary-tree

The function `int IsOnMinLevel(Heap H, int i)`, returns if the node of index `i` is on a `min level (even level)`, in `constant time`

functions provided:

```c
typedef struct heap
{
    int *array;
    int count;  
    int capacity;   
} *Heap;

Heap CreateHeap(int capacity)
{
    Heap h=(Heap) malloc(sizeof(struct heap));
    h->count=0;
    h->capacity=capacity;
    h->array=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*h->capacity);
    if(! h->array) return NULL;
    return h;
}
int Parent(Heap h, int i)
{
    if(i<=0 || i>=h->count)     
        return -1;
    return ((i-1)/2);
}
int LeftChild(Heap h, int i)
{
    int left = 2*i+1;
    if(left>=h->count) return -1;
    return left;
}
int RightChild(Heap h, int i)
{
    int right = 2*i+2;
    if(right>=h->count) 
        return -1;
    return right;
}
void ResizeHeap(Heap *h)
{
    int i;
    int *array_old = (*h)->array;
    (*h)->array=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*(*h)->capacity*2);    
 
    for(i=0; i<(*h)->capacity; i++) 
        (*h)->array[i]=array_old[i];    
    (*h)->capacity *=2;
    free(array_old);
}
```

How do I get `level` from `index`? And is there a relation between `level` and `index` in a `complete binary tree`?

Comment: Assuming the heap uses 0-based indexing, and that the root is on level 1, then given index `i`, the level is `floor(log2(i+1)) + 1`

Comment: @user3386109 shouldn't it be ```floor(log2(i+1))``` instead of ```floor(log2(i+1)) + 1```?

Comment: The implementation of `log` (or an integer variant such as `ilog2` - floor of log to the base 2) is generally bounded such that it does not depend (much) on the argument, so can be considered to be O(1).

Comment: @IanAbbott but since it's ```floor(log2(i+1))```, then ```index 0 = 1 | index 1 = 2 | index 2 = 2``` and so on, and it seems that the level numbering starts from ```level 1``` not ```level 0```

Comment: @Dancchi Yes, you are correct. I shall delete my misleasing comment.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the level of the first few nodes:

```
index: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 ...
level: 0 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 ...
```

The pattern is pretty simple: a new level starts at index `2^k-1`. So if a node has an index between `2^k-1` included and `2^(k+1)-1` excluded, then it is at level `k`.

You can derive a formula from this: for a node with index `i`, find `k` such that `2^k-1 <= i < 2^(k+1)-1`.
Add 1: `2^k <= i+1 < 2^(k+1)`.
Take the log2: `k <= log2(i+1) < k+1`.
Since `k` and `k+1` are consecutive integers, this is equivalent to `floor(log2(i+1)) = k`.

It turns out the function `floor(log2(i))` when `i` is an integer can be very efficiently written, for example like this ([taken from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24748637/3854570)):

```
int uint64_log2(uint64_t n)
{
    #define S(k) if (n >= (UINT64_C(1) << k)) { i += k; n >>= k; }
    int i = -(n == 0); S(32); S(16); S(8); S(4); S(2); S(1); return i;
    #undef S
}
```

With this, your function becomes:

```
int IsOnMinLevel(Heap H, int i)
{
    return uint64_log2(i+1) % 2 == 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer Given by [@user3386109](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3386109/user3386109):

> Assuming the heap uses 0-based indexing, and that the root is on level 1, then given index `i`, the level is `floor(log2(i+1)) + 1`

The function is simply:

```c
int IsOnMinLevel(Heap H, int i)
{
    return ((int)(floor(log2(i+1))) % 2) == 0; //cast to int since log2 gives double
}
```