# Get highest number with n bits

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I'd like to get the highest number with n bits in C++. I've written this piece of code but maybe there is a more efficient way.

```cpp
int A = 22;  // 10110
int max = pow(2, (int) log2(A) + 1) - 1;  // returns 31 (11111)
```

This code raises 2 to the power of the number of bits of A and subtracts 1.

**Edit**

Since the question seems unclear here are some more examples to help understand the result I want to achieve.

- `1000` => `1111`
- `1010` => `1111`
- `100001` => `111111`
- `111` => `111`

Comment: Any C++ code that calls `pow()` with two integer values is automatically broken, by default. This is not what `pow()` is for. You might be surprised to learn that, for example, `pow(10,2)` will not produce for you `100`. And, yes, there's a better way, simply by using a constant that the C++ library already defines for you, that means exactly this.

Comment: "Maximize a number" means to set all the bits to the right of the left-most set bit in a number? What is the range of numbers you are want to support? what should happen to negative numbers?

Comment: what does "to maximize a number" mean? Like, mathematically?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik can you tell me more?

Comment: TIp: You can "pow" factors of 2 using `<<`.

Comment: `pow()` takes the natural logarithm of its first parameter, multiplies it by the 2nd parameter, then raises the mathematical `e` constant to the result. This is calculated using floating point math, and, as you know, [floating point math is broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/). As such, you are not guaranteed that `pow(10,2)` will be exactly 100.

Comment: `highest number with n bits` What is "highest number"? Why `0b111111000000....` is not higher than `0b11111`?

Comment: even if you are lucky you'd get `100.0`, but thats not what you want, because its a floating point number while you are workign with integers

Comment: @pasta64 -- This behavior of floating point not only exists in C++, but in most of the other languages also.  The bottom line is to not use floating point functions to solve integer-based problems.

Comment: *"I'd like to get the highest number with n bits"* Please elaborate on that with more examples. Do you want the sequence 1, 3, 7, 15, ...?

Comment: Yes @Bob__, these are the numbers I'm looking for

Comment: 11111 isn't the highest number with 22 bits

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, implement log2 using [How to do an integer log2() in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/994593/how-to-do-an-integer-log2-in-c) . Then shift to the position one more than the highest bit, and then subtract one to get all bits set.

```
int A = 22;
unsigned max = (1u << std::bit_width((unsigned)A)) - 1;
```

Note: this will work up to around `UINT_MAX >> 1`, as `1u <<` will overflow.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a Bit Twiddling problem. This is based on [https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#RoundUpPowerOf2](https://graphics.stanford.edu/%7Eseander/bithacks.html#RoundUpPowerOf2), just without the final increment.

```
unsigned int v;
v--;
v |= v >> 1;
v |= v >> 2;
v |= v >> 4;
v |= v >> 8;
v |= v >> 16;
```

This works for 32-bit numbers only, though, and is untested.

Comment: For 64-bit numbers, add another `v |= v >> 32;`

Comment: Explanation: all the 1 bits in the original number keep getting copied to the right and eventually fill in every possible spot to the right of where they started.

Answer (score 1):

The usual way of raises 2 to the power of the number of digits of A and subtracts 1 is much simpler to write and read.

```
Formula:  (1 << nb_bits) - 1

// example: mask lower 8 bits, same as highest number in 8 bits.

constexpr int mask = (1 << 8) - 1;  // 255

//  <=>    mask = 0b1'0000'0000 - 1  in hex:  0x0100 - 1
//  <=>    mash = 0b0'1111'1111      in hex:  0x00FF

// for numbers made of up to 127 bits, use 128 bits integer: 

// on gcc
__uint128_t largest_in_n_bits(int n) {
    assert(n < 128);
    return (__uint128_t(1) << n) - 1;
}
```

Comment: The problem for the OP is getting `nb_bits`.  They need to find that out from the value and that is resulting the expensive log call.

Comment: The questoin is literally: **"I'd like to get the highest number with n bits in C++"**

Answer (score 0):

Without any function call, I would propose this algorithm :

```
int a = 22;
short count = 0;
while(a != 0){
    a >>= 1;
    ++count;
}
for(int i=0; i<count; ++i){
    a |= 1;
    a <<= 1;
}
a >>= 1;
// a is now 31
```

There may be a classier way to do it, but this one only uses bit shifting.

Answer (score 0):

> I've written this piece of code but maybe there is a more efficient way.

I'll assume the question is "can this code be improved"?

Yes, it can.

What your code does is

1. convert the integer `A` to a `double`, implicitly, because `log2(double)` takes a `double` argument.
2. Take the logarithm base 2 of that `(double)A` using the `log2(double)` function.
3. round down that `double` to the nearest `int`, then add 1
4. Convert the result to a `double` again, then use the `pow(double, double)` function to approximate 2.0 ** that.
5. convert the result down, hoping (sadly, incorrectly) that the result is correct.

So, first, the obvious, `pow` is just useless in your case. Use bit shifts; `1 << k` shifts 1 left by `k` bit positions; the result is 2**k.

Then, detecting the highest set bit in an integer is a solved problem: [What is the fastest/most efficient way to find the highest set bit (msb) in an integer in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671815/what-is-the-fastest-most-efficient-way-to-find-the-highest-set-bit-msb-in-an-i)