# log2 in python math module

Tags: python, math

why doesn't it exist?

```
import math
[x for x in dir(math) if 'log' in x]
>>> ['log', 'log10', 'log1p']
```

I know I can do log(x,2), but log2 is really common, so I'm kind of baffled.

Oh, it looks like it's only defined in C99, not C90, I guess that answers my question. Still seems kind of silly.

Answer (score 55):

I think you've answered your own question.  :-) There's no `log2(x)` because you can do `log(x, 2)`.  As The Zen of Python ([PEP 20](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)) says, "There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it."

That said, `log2` was considered in [Issue3366](http://bugs.python.org/issue3366) (scroll down to the last 3 messages) which added several other C99 math functions to the `math` module for Python 2.7 and 3.2.

**Edit**: log2 was reconsidered in [Issue11888](http://bugs.python.org/issue11888) and added in Python 3.3.

Comment: That begs the question, why does `log10` exist?

Comment: log10 is C89, so it exists on all common platforms, including Windows.  So it's trivial for Python to add a wrapper round it.

Comment: Well, fair enough. I guess people like log10 enough to include it specially but not log2. It looks like it's actually in numpy, so that solves that.

Comment: [The docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.log10) actually recommend that you use `log10(x)` instead of `log(x, 10)`: "math.log10(x) Return the base-10 logarithm of x. This is usually more accurate than log(x, 10)"  So is `log(x, 2)` less accurate than a dedicated implementation?

Comment: For example, if you try to find the power of 2 greater than or equal to 2**29 (= itself), using `2**ceil(log(n, 2))`, you'll get the wrong answer, because `math.log(n, 2)` = 29.000000000000004 instead of 29.0. `np.log2(n)` = 29.0 exactly, so produces the correct answer.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure that there is that you want, but:

-- From math point of view you can do for example math.log(x)/math.log(2).

-- If input X has an integral type and you are waiting for the integral rounded result - you can do it rather faster with right shifting. This works with SHR command and without Taylor series + local interpolation, which is under the hood of libc log() calls.

Comment: -- But from a numerical precision or good coding point of view, don't.

Comment: Yes, combinations of i.bit-length, i>>x, i/2**x, and/or log2 can get you more bits or faster results than log2 alone.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else arriving this late, Python 3.3 and later has math.log2.  It's "usually more accurate than log(x, 2)," or log(x)/log(2), I would guess.  There is also int.bit_length().

[Log to the base 2 in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3719631/log-to-the-base-2-in-python/28033134)

https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html