# Log to the base 2 in python

Tags: python, logarithm

How should I compute log to the base two in python. Eg. I have this equation where I am using log base 2

```
import math
e = -(t/T)* math.log((t/T)[, 2])
```

Comment: logbase2(x) = log(x)/log(2)

Comment: What you have should work if you take the square brackets out around the ", 2" in the `math.log()` call. Have you tried it?

Comment: math.log(value, base)

Comment: As to clarify [`math.log(x[, base])`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.log): Square brackets in documentation often indicate optional arguments.

Answer (score 292, accepted):

It's good to know that

[image: log_b(a) = log(a)/log(b)]

but also know that
`math.log` takes an optional second argument which allows you to specify the base:

```
In [22]: import math

In [23]: math.log?
Type:       builtin_function_or_method
Base Class: <type 'builtin_function_or_method'>
String Form:    <built-in function log>
Namespace:  Interactive
Docstring:
    log(x[, base]) -> the logarithm of x to the given base.
    If the base not specified, returns the natural logarithm (base e) of x.


In [25]: math.log(8,2)
Out[25]: 3.0
```

Comment: `base` argument added in version 2.3, btw.

Comment: What is this '?' syntax ? I can't find reference for it.

Comment: @wap26: Above, I'm using the [IPython](http://ipython.org/) interactive interpreter. One of its features (accessed with the `?`) is [dynamic object introspection](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/rel-0.13.1/overview.html#main-features-of-the-interactive-shell).

Answer (score 105):

Depends on whether the input or output is `int` or `float`.

```
assert 5.392317422778761 ==   math.log2(42.0)
assert 5.392317422778761 ==    math.log(42.0, 2.0)
assert 5                 ==  math.frexp(42.0)[1] - 1
assert 5                 ==            (42).bit_length() - 1
```

## float → float [`math.log2(x)`](https://docs.python.org/library/math.html#math.log2)

```
import math

log2 = math.log(x, 2.0)
log2 = math.log2(x)   # python 3.3 or later
```

- Thanks [@akashchandrakar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26955373/673991) and [@unutbu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3719686/673991).

---

## float → int [`math.frexp(x)`](https://docs.python.org/library/math.html#math.frexp)

If all you need is the integer part of log base 2 of a floating point number, extracting the exponent is pretty efficient:

```
log2int_slow = int(math.floor(math.log(x, 2.0)))    # these give the
log2int_fast = math.frexp(x)[1] - 1                 # same result
```

- Python frexp() calls the [C function frexp()](http://people.freebsd.org/%7Ejake/frexp.c) which just grabs and tweaks the exponent.
- Python frexp() returns a tuple (mantissa, exponent). So `[1]` gets the exponent part.
- For integral powers of 2 the exponent is one more than you might expect.  For example 32 is stored as 0.5x2⁶.  This explains the `- 1` above.  Also works for 1/32 which is stored as 0.5x2⁻⁴.
- Floors toward negative infinity, so log₂31 computed this way is 4 not 5.  log₂(1/17) is -5 not -4.

---

## int → int [`x.bit_length()`](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#int.bit_length)

If both input and output are integers, this native integer method could be very efficient:

```
log2int_faster = x.bit_length() - 1
```

- `- 1` because 2ⁿ requires n+1 bits. Works for very large integers, e.g. `2**10000`.
- Floors toward negative infinity, so log₂31 computed this way is 4 not 5.

Comment: Interesting. So you're subtracting 1 there because the mantissa is in the range [0.5, 1.0)? I would give this one a few more upvotes if I could.

Comment: Exactly right @LarsH.  32 is stored as 0.5x2⁶ so if you want log₂32=5 you need to **subtract 1**.  Also true for 1/32 which is stored as 0.5x2⁻⁴.

Answer (score 20):

If you are on python 3.3 or above then it already has a built-in function for computing log2(x)

```
import math
'finds log base2 of x'
answer = math.log2(x)
```

If you are on older version of python then you can do like this

```
import math
'finds log base2 of x'
answer = math.log(x)/math.log(2)
```

Answer (score 11):

Using numpy:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: np.log2?
Type:           function
Base Class:     <type 'function'>
String Form:    <function log2 at 0x03049030>
Namespace:      Interactive
File:           c:\python26\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\ufunclike.py
Definition:     np.log2(x, y=None)
Docstring:
    Return the base 2 logarithm of the input array, element-wise.

Parameters
----------
x : array_like
  Input array.
y : array_like
  Optional output array with the same shape as `x`.

Returns
-------
y : ndarray
  The logarithm to the base 2 of `x` element-wise.
  NaNs are returned where `x` is negative.

See Also
--------
log, log1p, log10

Examples
--------
>>> np.log2([-1, 2, 4])
array([ NaN,   1.,   2.])

In [3]: np.log2(8)
Out[3]: 3.0
```

Answer (score 7):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_logarithm

```
def lg(x, tol=1e-13):
  res = 0.0

  # Integer part
  while x<1:
    res -= 1
    x *= 2
  while x>=2:
    res += 1
    x /= 2

  # Fractional part
  fp = 1.0
  while fp>=tol:
    fp /= 2
    x *= x
    if x >= 2:
        x /= 2
        res += fp

  return res
```

Comment: Extra points for an algorithm that can be adapted to always give the correct integer part, unlike int(math.log(x, 2))

Answer (score 6):

```
>>> def log2( x ):
...     return math.log( x ) / math.log( 2 )
... 
>>> log2( 2 )
1.0
>>> log2( 4 )
2.0
>>> log2( 8 )
3.0
>>> log2( 2.4 )
1.2630344058337937
>>>
```

Comment: This is built in to the `math.log` function.  See unutbu's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this ,

```
import math
print(math.log(8,2))  # math.log(number,base)
```

Answer (score 2):

In python 3 or above, math class has the following functions

```
import math

math.log2(x)
math.log10(x)
math.log1p(x)
```

or you can generally use `math.log(x, base)` for any base you want.

Comment: maybe a link couldn't harm https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.log1p

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget that *log[base A] x = log[base B] x / log[base B] A*.

So if you only have `log` (for natural log) and `log10` (for base-10 log), you can use

```
myLog2Answer = log10(myInput) / log10(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `help` method

```
>>> import math
>>> help(math.log)

Help on built-in function log in module math:

log(...)
    log(x, [base=math.e])
    Return the logarithm of x to the given base.
    
    If the base not specified, returns the natural logarithm (base e) of x.
(END)
```

> log(x, [base=math.e])
>
> Return the logarithm of x to the given base.