# An interesting result when I typecast te output

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am observing an interesting result when I typecast an output:

Here is the code snippet:

```
int bitSize = (int)log10(1.0*16)/log10(2.0);   //bistsize = 3  it should be 4
int temp = log10(1.0*16)/log10(2.0);           //temp = 4
```

Basically I want to take log2(16) which should be 4. I think my understanding of typecasting is wrong. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: I'm assuming your code uses variables and not hard coded values :)

Comment: You say you "..want to take log2(16).." but then you call `log10(..)` or am i being thick (maths was never my strongest subject!)

Comment: @Tony: Not all compilers support `log2`. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/758001/log2-not-found-in-my-math-h/766669#766669

Comment: no I am not using hard coded values :) It was just for illustration

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are only casting the output of the first `log(..)` function. Put parenthesis around the entire expression:

```
int bitSize = (int)(log10(1.0*16)/log10(2.0));
```

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
int bitSize = static_cast<int>(log10(1.0*16)/log10(2.0));
```

One of the niceties of the new C++ casts is that they parenthesize the argument, so it's clear exactly what you're casting.

Comment: Ohh yeah you guys are right. The whole thing needs to be put inside bracket! I will read about static cast though.