# What the function calcHist() give us

Tags: image, opencv, computer-vision, histogram, entropy

My question is when we normalize the histogram , is there any build-in function for that , if not than obviously we can calculate the histogram of the image using the function `calcHist()` , but the formula of normalizing histogram is `Nk/N` so what `calcHist` return us is `N` in this formula , or we have to calculate `N` on our own , and whats its role in entropy formula

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure I get your question. But here is a simple example of how to get the l1 normalised histogram of a grayscale image with OpenCV.

In case of an image `N` is the number of pixels which can be computed simply by multiplying the width and the height of the image. Then it is simply a matter of dividing the histogram by `N`.

```c
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Mat img = imread(argv[1],CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
    Mat hist;

    int channels[] = {0};
    int histSize[] = {32};
    float range[] = { 0, 256 };
    const float* ranges[] = { range };

    calcHist( &img, 1, channels, Mat(), // do not use mask
         hist, 1, histSize, ranges,
         true, // the histogram is uniform
         false );

   Mat histNorm = hist / (img.rows * img.cols);

   return 0;
}
```

To get the example I modified the one from the OpenCV [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/histograms.html).

If you want to compute the entropy with this histogram, you can do this:

```c
double entropy = 0.0;
for (int i=0; i<histNorm.rows; i++)
{
    float binEntry = histNorm.at<float>(i,0);
    if (binEntry != 0.0)
        entropy -= binEntry * log2(binEntry);
}
```

Comment: I want to subtract the two frame with sufficient time gap ,so that entropy clearly represent the area where change occured , `if (binEntry == 0.0)` than it lead to infinity , what can do for this

Comment: Just handle them as I did in my example: Ignore the empty bins.

Comment: how to add the time gap ? any info about that ?

Comment: You simply save on frame, wait a certain amount of time and save another frame. As simple as that. If you have problems with that, maybe you can open another question where you show, what you have got so far and at which point you have problems.

Comment: This means your compiler does not support it. But you can simply emulate it by computing `log(value)/log(2.0)` instead. See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/758001/log2-not-found-in-my-math-h)

Comment: Don't you think your loop should be something like this : `for (int i=0; i&lt;histNorm.rows; i++)
   {
      float binEntry = histNorm.at&lt;float&gt;(i,0);` because your loop focus is only on one row ? which is deciding about the whole image

Comment: We are looping over a histogram, which is one dimensional. Not the two dimensional image.

Comment: but my image is 2dimensional , isn't it affect ?

Comment: Not if you make computations on the histogram and not on the image.