# how to handle the entropy of two images from .mp4

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, entropy

i am working on entropy , i am getting consecutive frames from .mp4 file , i want to count the entropy of current frame with previous frame , if the entropy between them is not zero than it should check the frame , otherwise it should ignore the frame , it should save the previous frame and take the current frame after 2 sec, if entropy is zero it should ignore it and than again wait for 2 sec Here is my code :

```
capture.open("recog.mp4");
if (!capture.isOpened()) {
    cerr << "can not open camera or video file" << endl;
}

while(1)
{
    capture >> current_frame;
    if (current_frame.empty())
        break;
    if (! previous_frame.empty())  {
       subtract(current_frame, previous_frame, pre_img);
       Mat hist;
       int channels[] = {0};
       int histSize[] = {32};
       float range[] = { 0, 256 };
       const float* ranges[] = { range };

       calcHist( &pre_img, 1, channels, Mat(), // do not use mask
                 hist, 1, histSize, ranges,
                 true, // the histogram is uniform
                 false );

       Mat histNorm = hist / (pre_img.rows * pre_img.cols);
       double entropy = 0.0;
       for (int i=0; i<histNorm.rows; i++)
       {
          float binEntry = histNorm.at<float>(i,0);
          if (binEntry != 0.0)
          {
            entropy -= binEntry * log(binEntry);
          }
          else
          {
            //ignore the frame andgo for next , but how to code it ? is any function with ignore ?
          }
waitKey(10);
current_frame.copyTo(previous_frame); 
}
```

This is counting the entropy of only one image that is current image and it become previous image when the next image come into process , as far my page work told me. It give me error in log2 when i use it like this `entropy -= binEntry * log2(binEntry);` and can you please help me in telling that how to ignore the frame when the entropy is zero , so that .mp4 continue running and should i need to use `cvwaitkey(2)` to check .mp4 after 2 sec , mean .mp4is running but i am ignoring the frames

ignore mean when it subtract the current frame from the previous and entropy is 0, than previous frame remain previous , current not become previous , and previous wait 2sec for the next current image , and than perform the task on it

Answer (score 1):

To ignore a certain amount of frames simply read them from the stream.

```
for(int i=0; i<60; i++)
    capture >> current_frame;
```

If your video has 30fps this would skip 2 seconds of video.

To act in case your entropy is greater than a certain threshold you need to add something like this:

```
if ( entropy > 1.0 )
{
    // do something
}
```

I used a threshold, because due to noise the entropy probably will never be zero between different frames.

If your compiler does not offer you the `log2` function you can simply emulate it as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/758001/log2-not-found-in-my-math-h).

Comment: @soetschie But the main question is still there , how to handle with 2 successive frames from .mp4 video , when i assign entropy value to the current frames , that current frame become previous frame in the next iteration , the value mix , so how to assign the value to them so that i can subtract the value of two frames which are current and the previous frames , i want to subtract the current frame entropy from the previous frame entropy

Comment: You could handle it just like you do it with the frames: with two variables previous_entropy and current_entropy. But you are already computing the entropy on the difference of two images. So you want to monitor the change of the change?

Comment: That difference of two images is for subtracting the background from , this subtraction is for detecting the change in the frame , if the frame is bigger , like it contain the vehicle than it should process that frame

Comment: Are you sure the formula uses the log2 ? or its simple log ? because i am getting different formula's

Comment: @sietschie Are you sure about your loop in the answer ?

Comment: Usually log2 is used for that. But since the difference is just a constant factor it is not much of a difference. And I have not tested the loop, but the idea should apply.

Comment: if you apply `i<60` than it mean it run just of 2 sec video ? isn't it `i=i+60`

Comment: Of course you need to adjust the value of 60. It depends on the time you want to skip and the frames per second of your video. Skipping frames by incrementing i with larger values does not work, since you need to read every frame in-between.