# Entropy change the values on every execution

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, entropy

Here is code which i am using in my program :

```
calcHist( &pre_img, 1, channels, Mat(), // do not use mask
                 hist, 1, histSize, ranges,
                 true, // the histogram is uniform
                 false );

       Mat histNorm = hist / (pre_img.rows * pre_img.cols);
       double entropy = 0.0;
       for (int i=0; i<histNorm.rows; i++)
       {
          float binEntry = histNorm.at<float>(i,0);
          if (binEntry != 0.0)
          {
            entropy -= binEntry * log(binEntry);
          }
       }
       cout<<entropy<<endl;
```

The first thing is when ever i enter it like `entropy -= binEntry * log2(binEntry);` it give me error on `log2` , i added the libraries of math and numeric in VS 2010 , but still getting the error and the second point in the code is whenever i run it on the same video it give me different values on every execution , like if it give me `10.0 , 2.0 , 0.05` than the same frame on the next time running the program show me `8.0 , 1.5 , 0.01` `these are sample values not exact`

Comment: What errors are you seeing?

Comment: @AlanStokes `Identifier log2 is not defined`

Comment: Do you have `#include <math.h>`?

Comment: @AlanStokes Yes , i am using it

Comment: @AlanStokes I am using three libraries for it , `#include <math.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <numeric>`

Comment: maybe you can use log instead?

Comment: @computer I am using only `log` and its not showing me error , but the formula ths using `log2` and whenever i run the program it give me different values on every execution

Comment: @Pieter you can use log to reproduce log2. Would it be sufficient to solve your problem?

Comment: `log2` is only defined in the C99 standard. Try to [define function `log2` yourself](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/758001/log2-not-found-in-my-math-h)

Answer (score 1):

`log2` is only defined in the C99 standard. A workaround for not using `log2` might be to replace it with different base because the logarithm `logb(x)` can be computed from the logarithms of `x` and `b` with respect to an arbitrary base `k` using the following formula:

[image]

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/131719/29621

so you can replace

```
if (binEntry != 0.0)
          {
            entropy -= binEntry * log2(binEntry);
          }
```

with

```
if (binEntry != 0.0)
          {
            entropy -= binEntry * log(binEntry)/log(2.0);
                                                     ^
                                                also you should use `log(2.0)`
                                                because the argument should be
                                                double or float
          }
```

Comment: You didn't get my question , i am say i have error in declaring `log2` even `log(2)` , your code still showing the error

Comment: can you use other math functions?

Comment: I am using three libraries for it , `#include <math.h> #include <cmath> #include <numeric>`

Comment: can you use any other function from math.h, i.e. sin?

Comment: Try `log(2.0)` because the argument should be `double` of `float`

Comment: @computer Your answer missing this part : `whenever i run it on the same video it give me different values on every execution , like if it give me 10.0 , 2.0 , 0.05 than the same frame on the next time running the program show me 8.0 , 1.5 , 0.01`

Comment: do this happen now, when you use log?

Comment: @computer yes it happens