# Calculate entropy of a file

Tags: c++, python, math, count, entropy

I have tried to search this function for over two hours from google, forums, wikipedia and many, many forums but I couldn't find it. How I can do this? I tried the following but it didn't work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>

static unsigned int mylog2 (unsigned int val) {
 unsigned int ret = -1;
 while (val != 0) {
    val >>= 1;
    ret++;
 }
 return ret;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
FILE            *pFile;
int             i;              // various loop index
int             j;              // filename loop index
int             n;              // Bytes read by fread;
int             size;           // Filesize
float           entropy;
float           temp;           // temp value used in entropy calculation
long            alphabet[256];
unsigned char   buffer[1024];


/* do this for all files */
for(j = 1; j < argc; j++)
{
    /* initialize all values */
    size = 0;
    entropy = 0.0;
    memset(alphabet, 0, sizeof(long) * 256);

    pFile = fopen(argv[j], "rb");
    if(pFile == NULL)
    {
        printf("Failed to open `%s`\n", argv[j]);
        continue;
    }

    /* Read the whole file in parts of 1024 */
    while((n = fread(buffer, 1, 1024, pFile)) != 0)
    {
        /* Add the buffer to the alphabet */
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            alphabet[(int) buffer[i]]++;
            size++;
        }
    }
    fclose(pFile);

    /* entropy calculation */
    for (i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        if (alphabet[i] != 0)
        {
            temp = (float) alphabet[i] / (float) size;
            entropy += -temp * mylog2(temp);
        }
    }
    printf("%02.5f [ %02.5f ]\t%s\n", entropy, entropy / 8, argv[j]);
 } // outer for 
 return 0;
}
```

I know I am doing it wrong. In python it's seems to be a lot easier, in python it is:

```
import sys
import math

if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    print "Usage: file_entropy.py [path]filename"
    sys.exit()

# read the whole file into a byte array
f = open(sys.argv[1], "rb")
byteArr = map(ord, f.read())
f.close()
fileSize = len(byteArr)
print 'File size in bytes:'
print fileSize
print

# calculate the frequency of each byte value in the file
freqList = []
for b in range(256):
    ctr = 0
    for byte in byteArr:
        if byte == b:
            ctr += 1
    freqList.append(float(ctr) / fileSize)
# print 'Frequencies of each byte-character:'
# print freqList
# print

# Shannon entropy
ent = 0.0
for freq in freqList:
    if freq > 0:
        ent = ent + freq * math.log(freq, 2)
ent = -ent
print 'Shannon entropy (min bits per byte-character):'
print ent
print
print 'Min possible file size assuming max theoretical compression efficiency:'
print (ent * fileSize), 'in bits'
print (ent * fileSize) / 8, 'in bytes'

###  Modifications to file_entropy.py to create the Histogram start here ###
### by Ken Hartman  www.KennethGHartman.com

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = len(freqList)

ind = np.arange(N)  # the x locations for the groups
width = 1.00        # the width of the bars

#fig = plt.figure()
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(11,5),dpi=100)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
rects1 = ax.bar(ind, freqList, width)
ax.set_autoscalex_on(False)
ax.set_xlim([0,255])

ax.set_ylabel('Frequency')
ax.set_xlabel('Byte')
ax.set_title('Frequency of Bytes 0 to 255\nFILENAME: ' + sys.argv[1])

plt.show()
```

How to achieve the same in C++ ? Hopefully somebody answers factually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must not compute the integral part of the logarithm in base 2. To compute logarithm in base2 in C you can use `log2` from `math.h`.

Comment: You may have to convert bases, but it's easy to do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/758001/log2-not-found-in-my-math-h

Comment: VERSIONS
       These functions first appeared in glibc in version 2.1.

CONFORMING TO
       C99, POSIX.1-2001.  The variant returning double also conforms to SVr4, 4.3BSD.

Answer (score 1):

The Shannon entropy is `H= -1*sum(p_i*log(p_i))` where **p_i** is the *frequency of each symbol i (the sum) and the result is in bits per symbol if the log base is 2*, **"nats"** *if the log base is n*.  But it changes if you change how you express the data, i.e. if the same data is expressed as bit, bytes, etc. So you can **divide by log(n)** where *n is the number of symbols available (2 for binary, 256 for bytes) and H will range from 0 to 1 (this is normalized intensive Shannon entropy)*.

The above entropy is an **"intensive"** form, i.e. per symbol which is analogous to specific entropy in physics, per kg or per mole.   Regular "extensive" entropy like physics entropy is `S=N*H` where N is the number of symbols in the file. A little math with the above H gives **normalized extensive entropy for a file**, where "n" is number of distinct "i" symbols (2 for binary, 256 for bytes):

```
S=N * H / log(n) = sum(count_i*log(N/count_i))/log(n)
```

For files with equal frequency of each symbol this gives `S=N`.  Entropy does not do any compression on the data and is thereby completely ignorant of any patterns so 000000111111 has same H and S as 010111101000  (6 1's and 6 0's in both cases).